# Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter

Tags: jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I have a survey on a website, and there seems to be some issues with the users hitting enter (I don't know why) and accidentally submitting the survey (form) without clicking the submit button. Is there a way to prevent this?

I'm using HTML, PHP 5.2.9, and jQuery on the survey.

Comment: Don't use form tags and do custom ajax request :) But sure, you can go ahead with the key-listening and prevention approach, that's what I'd do..

Comment: I just don't use the form tags because I prefer to process forms through ajax requests by non-conventional ways (i.e: submitting some fields as their focus are dropped, etc). You can also make a special listener to catch Enter key and process it only if you want to do it.

Answer (score 1039, accepted):

You can use a method such as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

In reading the comments on the original post, to make it more usable and allow people to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> if they have completed all the fields:

```
function validationFunction() {
  $('input').each(function() {
    ...

  }
  if(good) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if( (event.keyCode == 13) && (validationFunction() == false) ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm currently just looking for a quick fix, and don't have time to implement validation items.  I appreciate everyone's answers, but this is the one i'm going to go with in the mean time.  thank you.

Comment: Hi @Simon_Weaver and @Phil-carter - My code happens in a switch case statement
$searchBox.keyup(function (event)
`switch (event.keyCode){
    case 13:
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
        break;`
... then there's a bunch of other key codes being checked. 

In my case, this solution is not working at all. 

Any ideas **why**?

Comment: This method is unideal because it prevents the user from submitting the form by pressing enter while focused on the submit button.  The best solution would be that of BalusC below, where enter is interrupted only while still focused on the form inputs.

Comment: I've seen situations (Internet Explorer only) where you need to bind to `keydown` on the `document` instead of the `window` for this to work.

Comment: You might want to add `&& !$(document.activeElement).is('textarea')` to the condition, or else newlines inside a textarea are blocked (in IE at least).

Comment: This works in chrome but not in IE8 for me. The top answer here worked for me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585396/how-to-prevent-enter-keypress-to-submit-a-web-form

Comment: Why to use `event.preventDefault();` if we could just use `return false;`?

Comment: I can't make this work in Chrome. It looks like the events are not fired if the ENTER is pressed with the focus on a control inside a form.

Comment: If you need to deal with textarea, then have a look to BalusC answer, it has better explaination

Comment: Can someone explain to me why event.keyCode == 13? Is that specific number necessary or are there other options for this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: LIke others mentioned, I woudn't recommend this. At least attach it to a form. This prevents enter from being registered in Javascript. Technically it's not wrong..

Comment: this is not a good solution, you don't want to prevent all enters, only submit

Comment: This works for me. But this also prevent to add break line in textarea.

Comment: Very nice solution to stop in whole system with few lines. Lovely. :) But it has stopped the ENTER key in textarea as well. We should allow that somehow.

Comment: Event.keyCode is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode); instead, you should use [event.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).  This also lets you removes the magic integer 13--`if (event.key == "Enter") ...`

Comment: Below is a much easier and safer solution that does not the unintended side effect (ENTER on submit button does not work): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter/51507806#51507806

Comment: Oldie but goodie. Cannot count how many other solutions did not work for me.

Comment: Isn't it necessary to add `else return true;` to the event handler?

Answer (score 826):

### Disallow enter key anywhere

If you don't have a `<textarea>` in your form, then just add the following to your `<form>`:

```
<form ... onkeydown="return event.key != 'Enter';">
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$(document).on("keydown", "form", function(event) { 
    return event.key != "Enter";
});
```

This will cause that every key press inside the form will be checked on the `key`. If it is not `Enter`, then it will return `true` and anything continue as usual. If it is `Enter`, then it will return `false` and anything will stop immediately, so the form won't be submitted.

The [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) event is preferred over [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) as the `keyup` is too late to block form submit. Historically there was also the [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event), but this is deprecated, as is the [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode). You should use [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead which returns the name of the key being pressed. When `Enter` is checked, then this would check 13 (normal enter) as well as 108 (numpad enter).

Note that `$(window)` as suggested in some other answers instead of `$(document)` doesn't work for `keydown`/`keyup` in IE<=8, so that's not a good choice if you're like to cover those poor users as well.

### Allow enter key on textareas only

If you have a `<textarea>` in your form (which of course *should* accept the Enter key), then add the keydown handler to every individual input element which isn't a `<textarea>`.

```
<input ... onkeydown="return event.key != 'Enter';">
<select ... onkeydown="return event.key != 'Enter';">
...
```

To reduce boilerplate, this is better to be done with jQuery:

```
$(document).on("keydown", ":input:not(textarea)", function(event) {
    return event.key != "Enter";
});
```

If you have other event handler functions attached on those input elements, which you'd also like to invoke on enter key for some reason, then only prevent event's default behavior instead of returning false, so it can properly propagate to other handlers.

```
$(document).on("keydown", ":input:not(textarea)", function(event) {
    if (event.key == "Enter") {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

### Allow enter key on textareas and submit buttons only

If you'd like to allow enter key on submit buttons `<input|button type="submit">` too, then you can always refine the selector as below.

```
$(document).on("keydown", ":input:not(textarea):not(:submit)", function(event) {
    // ...
});
```

Note that `input[type=text]` as suggested in some other answers doesn't cover those HTML5 non-text inputs, so that's not a good selector.

Comment: This prevents enter key from working on any input other than textarea. It's not a good solution

Comment: This should be the correct answer since it does not interfere with other enter key listeners. Ones like Bootstrap tags input: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: I chose this solution because it wasn't even a full line of code I had to add. All things held equal, shorter answers are better.

Comment: Below is a much easier solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter/51507806#51507806

Comment: THIS answer is how someone becomes a SO "millionaire"

Comment: I don't like this answer because it does not shoot at the heart of the problem. It does not even understand the problem. This is a blind fix meaning if you don't understand the root cause, it will strike you back. I prefer Daniel Trebien's answer below for the root case analysis and lighter solution.

Comment: Great answer! However I am suggesting selector to be `':input:not(textarea):not(:button):not(:submit):not(:reset):not(:image):not(:file)'` to allow ENTER key pressed on other buttons and controls where ENTER key is a valid key.

Answer (score 307):

[Section 4.10.22.2 Implicit submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/forms.html#implicit-submission) of the W3C HTML5 spec says:

> A [`form`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/forms.html#the-form-element) element's **default button** is the first [submit button](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/forms.html#concept-submit-button) in [tree order](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/infrastructure.html#tree-order) whose [form owner](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/forms.html#form-owner) is that [`form`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/forms.html#the-form-element) element.
>
> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text field is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a form whose [default button](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/forms.html#default-button) has a defined [activation behavior](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/dom.html#activation-behavior) must cause the user agent to [run synthetic click activation steps](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/dom.html#run-synthetic-click-activation-steps) on that [default button](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/forms.html#default-button).
>
> > **Note:** Consequently, if the [default button](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/forms.html#default-button) is disabled, the form is not submitted when such an implicit submission mechanism is used. (A button has no [activation behavior](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html5-20180327/dom.html#activation-behavior) when disabled.)

Therefore, a standards-compliant way to disable any implicit submission of the form is to place a disabled submit button as the first submit button in the form:

```html
<form action="...">
  <!-- Prevent implicit submission of the form -->
  <button type="submit" disabled style="display: none" aria-hidden="true"></button>

  <!-- ... -->

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

One nice feature of this approach is that it works *without JavaScript*; whether or not JavaScript is enabled, a standards-conforming web browser is required to prevent implicit form submission.

Comment: On one hand it's simple and prevents all the pitfalls suggested by the accepted answers. On the other hand, it feels like a slight exploitation of the standard. Kudos for including aria-* attribute. I would love to hear more feedback on this.

Comment: Also works as `<input type="submit" disabled style="display: none" aria-hidden="true" />` and you can reduce the size of your page by a few chars. :-P

Comment: IE 11 submits anyway.

Comment: `aria-hidden` is redundant here; `display: none` (and `hidden`) hides the element for all users. https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/

Comment: Additional problem with all the `$(document).on("keydown", "form", function()...`s is that if you use `<input form="id">` outside of the actual `<form>` they don't work. This one on the contrary - ingenious!

Comment: This does not work on Safari, other browsers seem okay

Comment: For me, even IE 11 does not submit.

Comment: This works on my current version of Safari on iOS

Comment: BIG BONUS: this just works, and, if the submit button is selected, it still submits, as intended.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Firefox anymore. Version 96 is installed.

Comment: Thanks you for giving an actual EXPLANATION of the problem, in addition to a proper solution. Blind workarounds when not understanding the problem are poor solutions.

Comment: @moonbas3 Working in firefox 110. Beautiful solution... tabbing to the real submit button and hitting enter still works, enter anywhere else does not do an unintentional submit.

Comment: I have the urge to make a new question without jquery in the tag and question and this as the answer

Comment: To work in Safari, Chrome and FF, had to do the following:

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="return false">
  <input type="submit" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;" onclick="return false;">
</input>
</form

Comment: The original answer works for me in Safari 16.6 on Mac OS.

Comment: Hahaha, so better than the accepted answer in therm of time cost, also, the rest of the enter inputs that work with Jquery still works

Answer (score 79):

If you use a script to do the actual submit, then you can add "return false" line to the onsubmit handler like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Calling submit() on the form from JavaScript will not trigger the event.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome, this will also disable submit buttons, which is fine if you want to trigger an onlick-event on the submit button itself. Ajax hint:
Add your function call before the return and the user can still hit the enter key without submitting the form to the page.

Comment: Worked for me on Chrome, IE-11, and Firefox and was the simplest solution to implement. Disabling the enter key on whole sections of the page, as some answers do, seems too extreme and prone to bugs.

Answer (score 70):

I had to catch all three events related to pressing keys in order to prevent the form from being submitted:

```
    var preventSubmit = function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log("caught ya!");
            event.preventDefault();
            //event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    }
    $("#search").keypress(preventSubmit);
    $("#search").keydown(preventSubmit);
    $("#search").keyup(preventSubmit);
```

You can combine all the above into a nice compact version:

```
    $('#search').bind('keypress keydown keyup', function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 13) { e.preventDefault(); }
    });
```

Comment: You could either chain the last 3 selectors or bind multiple events with one method like so `$("#search").bind('keypress keyup keydown',preventSubmit)`;

Comment: Because in an ASP.NET web form everything has to be nested in a `<form>` tag, the enter key *will* submit the form... This solution disabled the enter key and fixed the problem though, thanks @Dave! Then I enabled the enter key for certain fields by `id`.

Comment: @Upgradingdave How are you able to write "log()" instead of "console.log()"?

Comment: @radbyx ... good catch, it should be `console.log`, I updated my answer.

Comment: Note that with `keypress keyup keydown` you trigger any code in the if condition *twice*.

Answer (score 24):

Use:

```
$(document).on('keyup keypress', 'form input[type="text"]', function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

This solution works on all forms on a website (also on forms inserted with Ajax), preventing only <kbd>Enter</kbd>s in input texts. Place it in a document ready function, and forget this problem for a life.

Comment: I think the original answer `e.which` was fine; no need to change it to `e.keyCode`. Both return the value 13 for the enter key. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4471635/292060 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18184976/292060

Comment: This solution takes care of two solutions : 1.) Don't submit forms on enter 2.) Allows enter in the textareas

Answer (score 23):

I can't comment yet, so I'll post a new answer

Accepted answer is ok-ish, but it wasn't stopping submit on numpad enter. At least in current version of Chrome. I had to alter the keycode condition to this, then it works.

```
if(event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 169) {...}
```

Comment: The difference between Enter and Return - many Point-Of-Sales operators use the numpad exclusively. +1

Comment: Now *(05-21-2015)*, for both normal enter and numpad enter, keyCode is **13** [Chrome 42, IE 11, FIreFox 36]

Answer (score 22):

Instead of preventing users from pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which may seem unnatural, you can leave the form as is and add some extra client-side validation: When the survey is not finished the result is not sent to the server and the user gets a nice message telling what needs to be finished to complete the form. If you are using jQuery, try the Validation plugin:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

This will require more work than catching the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button, but surely it will provide a richer user experience.

Comment: This sounds good but optional fields are problematic, the user may press enter by mistake and the form will be submitted. I do not see how you are going to know when the _survey is not finished_ unless you put every field as required (no default choices, no blank fields allowed...)

Answer (score 21):

A nice simple little jQuery solution:

```
$("form").bind("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 I was looking for a jQuery alternative, instead of using normal JS like `var key = event.keyCode || event.which; if (key == 13) return false;`

Comment: technically this is still POJ just with a simpler jquery wrapper. the code that you've given is nearly the same thing.

Answer (score 21):

A completely different approach:

1. **The first `<button type="submit">` in the form will be activated on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.**
2. This is true even if the button is hidden with `style="display:none;`
3. **The script for that button can return `false`, which aborts the submission process.**
4. You can still have another `<button type=submit>` to submit the form. Just return `true` to cascade the submission.
5. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the real submit button is focussed will activate the real submit button.
6. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside `<textarea>` or other form controls will behave as normal.
7. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside `<input>` form controls will trigger the first `<button type=submit>`, which returns `false`, and thus nothing happens.

Thus:

```
<form action="...">
  <!-- insert this next line immediately after the <form> opening tag -->
  <button type=submit onclick="return false;" style="display:none;"></button>

  <!-- everything else follows as normal -->
  <!-- ... -->
  <button type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm, in Chrome and Firefox, an even shorter version would be <button disabled style="display:none;"><button>, which also has the virtue of not requiring JS to work. Safari simply ignores the button and so other stuff will happen as normal.

Comment: I really don't liked the "ignoring 13 keycode" way, so i started to thinking for some easy and tricky way, and this idea came to my mind and as i was scrolling down this page i saw this thread :). Plus one for mutual idea and of-course the best solution.

Comment: Perfect answer for me. I wanted a form to emulate a CLI so the user would press enter for each next field and then have a submit at the end.

Comment: oh brilliant , the last button can be like this to prevent duplication submit on rapid clicks : `<button onclick="this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();" type="submit"">submit</button>`

Comment: @ArashMoosapour please don't disable submit buttons if they have focus - doing so drops focus and is a mess for accessibility.

Comment: This is brilliant. Simple, uses the specs.

Comment: I don't see any effect of this hidden button in my Firefox

Comment: I don't see an effect in Chrome either

Comment: @РоманКоптев: tested just again in Chrome 116 MacOS .. the hidden button successfully blocks/captures the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, producing the desired effect of "nothing happens".

Answer (score 18):

It is my solution to reach the goal,
it is clean and effective.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
  if ($(document.activeElement).attr('type') == 'submit')
     return true;
  else return false;
});
```

Comment: Good on Firefox but not Safri

Comment: God bless Safari. Clicking a button doesn't focus it.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use `javascript:void(0)` to prevent form submission.

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0)" method="post">
    <label for="">Search</label>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: does not work when you specifically have `method="post"` on your form. For instance I want the form to be submitted by buttons, but not when pressing enter while focused in the input.

Comment: for that condition you can use above answers because this answer is based on prevent form submission by enter and click both. above example have `method="post"` in form and its works, check again.

Comment: This doesn't work for me

Answer (score 12):

Not putting a submit button could do. Just put a script to the input (type=button) or add eventListener if you want it to submit the data in the form.

Rather use this

```
<input type="button" onclick="event.preventDefault();this.closest('form').submit();">
```

than using this

```
<input type="submit">
```

Note: onclick is needed here to actually submit the form when clicked. By default, `type="button"` is not sufficient enough to submit.

Comment: AFAICT, this is the only working answer without any tradeoffs for my use cases.

Comment: Not putting a submit button would just prevent submission using <enter> key while the submit button is focused. It would not prevent form submission through text input field or textarea.

Answer (score 10):

This is the perfect way, You will not be redirected from your page

```
$('form input').keydown(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: This will prevent pressing "Enter" on the submit button, no? Maybe David's answer is better.

Answer (score 9):

Giving the form an action of 'javascript:void(0);' seems to do the trick

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
<input type="text" />
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('Hello');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Do not use **type="submit"** for inputs or buttons.
2. Use **type="button"** and use js [Jquery/angular/etc] to submit form to server.

Answer (score 7):

I needed to prevent only specific inputs from submitting, so I used a class selector, to let this be a "global" feature wherever I need it.

```
<input id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" class="idNoEnter" .... />
```

And this jQuery code:

```
$('.idNoEnter').keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Alternatively, if keydown is insufficient:

```
$('.idNoEnter').on('keypress keydown keyup', function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Some notes:

Modifying various good answers here, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key seems to work for `keydown` on all the browsers. For the alternative, I updated `bind()` to the `on()` method.

I'm a big fan of class selectors, weighing all the pros and cons and performance discussions. My naming convention is 'idSomething' to indicate jQuery is using it as an id, to separate it from CSS styling.

Comment: This works on the textbox elements in the form. As you type, and hit enter in the textbox, the default behavior submits the form. This intercepts the enter key and prevents it from submitting.

Answer (score 6):

You could make a JavaScript method to check to see if the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key was hit, and if it is, to stop the submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function noenter() {
  return !(window.event && window.event.keyCode == 13); }
</script>
```

Just call that on the submit method.

Answer (score 6):

There are many good answers here already, I just want to contribute something from a UX perspective. Keyboard controls in forms are *very* important.

The question is how to disable from submission on keypress `Enter`. Not how to ignore `Enter` in an entire application. So consider attaching the handler to a form element, not the window.

Disabling `Enter` for form submission should still allow the following:

1. Form submission via `Enter` when submit button is focused.
2. Form submission when all fields are populated.
3. Interaction with non-submit buttons via `Enter`.

This is just boilerplate but it follows all three conditions.

```js
$('form').on('keypress', function(e) {
  // Register keypress on buttons.
  $attr = $(e.target).attr('type');
  $node = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
  if ($attr === 'button' || $attr === 'submit' || $node === 'textarea') {
    return true;
  }

  // Ignore keypress if all fields are not populated.
  if (e.which === 13 && !fieldsArePopulated(this)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Missing the conditional for `textarea` fields. The way it is, it's not creating new lines in `textarea` fields.

Comment: I believe this should be selected as the right answer!

Answer (score 6):

I have use this Code to disable 'ENTER' key press on both input type [text] and input type [password], you can add other too like input type [email] or also can apply on your desired Input type.

```
$(document).on('keyup keypress', 'form input[type="text"] , input[type="password"]', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

ONLY BLOCK SUBMIT but not other, important functionality of enter key, such as creating a new paragraph in a `<textarea>`:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  //set default value for variable that will hold the status of keypress
  pressedEnter = false;

  //if user pressed enter, set the variable to true
  if (event.keyCode == 13)
    pressedEnter = true;

  //we want forms to disable submit for a tenth of a second only
  setTimeout(function() {
    pressedEnter = false;
  }, 100)

})

//find all forms
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form')

//loop through forms
for (i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
  //listen to submit event
  forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    //if user just pressed enter, stop the submit event
    if (pressedEnter == true) {
      updateLog('Form prevented from submit.')
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

    updateLog('Form submitted.')
  })
}

var log = document.getElementById('log')
updateLog = function(msg) {
  log.innerText = msg
}
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #6f6f6f;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background: lightblue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Sample textarea (try enter key):</p>
  <textarea rows="4">Hit enter, a new line will be added. But the form won't submit</textarea><br/>
  <p>Sample textfield (try enter key):</p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  <h3 id="log"></h3>
</form>
```

Comment: wondering who and why would downvote this :| what's the issue with my solution?

Comment: Upvoted for the contribution. The accepted answer breaks most form UI, preventing "enter" from being registered on the entire application. Not good. I think it's a good idea to allow enter to be handled in form elements, particularly buttons so I like the path you're going down. I think this can be achieved without a timeout though. For example just look at the element attribute in your event handler. Allow 'button' and 'submit'

Comment: @NathanCH - This code does exactly the opposite from what you're saying. It *only prevents enter from submitting the form* and doesn't prevent any other functionality - for example, you might have a text field and want to use enter to create new paragraphs.

Comment: There's a typo in the first line. Instead of `function(e)` it should be `function(event)`. Otherwise, it works for me. Thank you.

Comment: @GuillermoPrandi thank you! That explains why the solution got some downvotes

Comment: why is `setTimeout(function() { pressedEnter = false; }, 100)` not inside the `event.keyCode == 13` condition?

Comment: This is an absolute lifesaver, since everything else prevents me from properly handling enter save events for things like grid inline edits. The only suggestion is to not use 'setTimeout' at all. I think that's the problem people have with this answer. It's too finicky. Instead, for the event do 
`on("keydown", function(event) {
   enterPressed = true;
}`
and then in the submit event, do 
`on("submit", function(e) {
    if (pressedEnter == true) {
      pressedEnter = false;
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;}`
This will ensure that it works no matter the delay.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Alpine, you can use the following to prevent form submission by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```html
<div x-data>
  <form x-on:keydown.prevent.enter="">...</form>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use the `.window` modifier to register the event listener on the root `window` object on the page instead of the element.

```html
<form>
  <div x-data>
    <input x-on:keydown.window.prevent.enter="" type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Life saver you are...

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on("keydown","form", function(event)
{
   node = event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
   type = $(event.target).prop('type').toLowerCase();

   if(node!='textarea' && type!='submit' && (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 169))
   {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

It works perfectly!

Comment: Out of interest, what keyboard key causes event keycode 169?

Answer (score 3):

If using Vue, use the following code to prevent users from submitting the form by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```html
<form @submit.prevent>...</form>
```

Comment: `<input ... @keypress.enter.prevent  />` also worked (Y)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similiar problem, where I had a grid with "ajax textfields" (Yii CGridView) and just one submit button. Everytime I did a search on a textfield and hit enter the form submitted. I had to do something with the button because it was the only common button between the views (MVC pattern). All I had to do was remove `type="submit"` and put `onclick="document.forms[0].submit()`

Answer (score 2):

I think it's well covered with all the answers, but if you are using a button with some JavaScript validation code you could just set the form's onkeypress for Enter to call your submit as expected:

```
<form method="POST" action="..." onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) mySubmitFunction(this); return false;">
```

The onkeypress JS could be whatever you need to do. There's no need for a larger, global change. This is especially true if you're not the one coding the app from scratch, and you've been brought into fix someone else's web site without tearing it apart and re-testing it.

Comment: I realize its a variant on Tom Hubbard's answer, which I +1'd because its actually what I did myself today before searching SO for other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Something I have not seen answered here: when you tab through the elements on the page, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you get to the submit button will trigger the onsubmit handler on the form, but it will record the event as a MouseEvent. Here is my short solution to cover most bases:

***This is not a jQuery-related answer***

#### HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" method=post>
  <input type="text" /><br />
  <input type="button" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="submit via mouse or keyboard" />
  <input type="button" onclick="submitMouseOnly(event)" value="submit via mouse only" />
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
window.submitMouseOnly=function(evt){
    let allow=(evt instanceof MouseEvent) && evt.x>0 && evt.y>0 && evt.screenX > 0 && evt.screenY > 0;
    if(allow)(evt.tagName=='FORM'?evt.target:evt.target.form).submit();
}
```

To find a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/nemesarial/6rhogva2/

Answer (score 1):

Using **Javascript** (without checking any input field):

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyIdentifier == 'U+000A' || e.keyIdentifier == 'Enter' || e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}, true);
</script>
```

If someone wants to apply this on specific fields, for example input type text:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyIdentifier == 'U+000A' || e.keyIdentifier == 'Enter' || e.keyCode == 13) {
        if (e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT' && e.target.type == 'text') {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
}, true);
</script>
```

This works well in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your css and add that to it then will automatically block the submission of your formular as long as you have submit input if you no longer want it you can delete it or type `activate` and `deactivate` instead

```
 input:disabled {
        background: gainsboro;
      }
      input[value]:disabled {
        color: whitesmoke;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

This disables enter key for all the forms on the page and does not prevent enter in textarea.

```
    // disable form submit with enter

    $('form input:not([type="submit"])').keydown((e) => {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case I had to stop ENTER from submitting the form and also simulate the clicking of the submit button. This is because the submit button had a click handler on it because we were within a modal window (inherited old code). In any case here's my combo solutions for this case.

```
    $('input,select').keypress(function(event) {
        // detect ENTER key
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            // simulate submit button click
            $("#btn-submit").click();
            // stop form from submitting via ENTER key press
            event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
        }
    });
```

This use case is specifically useful for people working with IE8.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
jQuery.each($("#your_form_id").find('input'), function(){
    $(this).bind('keypress keydown keyup', function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 13) { e.preventDefault(); }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a little CoffeeScript code (not field tested):

```
$ ->
    $(window).bind 'keypress', (event) ->
        if event.keyCode == 13
            unless {'TEXTAREA', 'SELECT'}[event.originalEvent.srcElement.tagName]
                event.preventDefault()
```

(I hope you like the nice trick in the unless clause.)

Answer (score -2):

This has worked for me in all browsers after much frustration with other solutions. The name_space outer function is just to stay away from declaring globals, something I also recommend.

```
$(function() {window.name_space = new name_space();}); //jquery doc ready
function name_space() {
    this.is_ie = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1);

    this.stifle = function(event) {
        event.cancelBubble;
        event.returnValue = false;
        if(this.is_ie === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
    }

    this.on_enter = function(func) {
        function catch_key(e) {
            var enter = 13;
            if(!e) {
                var e = event;
            }
            keynum = GetKeyNum(e);
            if (keynum === enter) {
                if(func !== undefined && func !== null) {
                    func();
                }
                return name_space.stifle(e);
            }
            return true; // submit
        }

        if (window.Event) {
            window.captureEvents(Event.KEYDOWN);
            window.onkeydown = catch_key;
        }
        else {
            document.onkeydown = catch_key;
        }

        if(name_space.is_ie === false) {
            document.onkeypress = catch_key;    
        }
    }
}
```

Sample use:

```
$(function() {
    name_space.on_enter(
        function () {alert('hola!');}
    );
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
// Validate your form using the jQuery onsubmit function... It'll really work...

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(#form).submit(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       if(validation())
          document.form1.submit();
   });
});

function validation()
{
   // Your form checking goes here.
}

<form id='form1' method='POST' action=''>
    // Your form data
</form>
```

Answer (score -3):

In my case I had a couple of [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) autocomplete fields and textareas in a form, so I definitely wanted them to accept <kbd>Enter</kbd>. So I removed the `type="submit"` input from a form and added an anchor `<a href="" id="btn">Ok</a>` instead. Then I styled it as a button and added the following code:

```
$( '#btn' ).click( function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( validateData() ){
        $( 'form#frm' ).append( '<input type="submit" id="frm-submit" style="display:none;"></input>' );
        setTimeout( function(){ $( '#frm-submit' ).click(); }, 500 );
    }
    return false;
});
```

If a user fills all required fields, `validateData()` succeeds and the form submits.