# Avoid a enter key submit for form $.ajax({}) - using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I do not want to submit a form $.ajax({}) when the enter key is hit, but with clicking the submit button.  Tried it with

```
$('#SubmitButton').click(function(event){

 if(event.keyCode==13) {
  //do something
 }

});
```

How do I get the above done.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Already anwered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't have a `key-` or `charCode` in `event.which` within a click event handler, so this doesn't make much sense at all. You would need to bind a `keypress` event to one or more input-text controls, where the user may type in (and therefore, trigger a return).

```
$('input:text').bind('keypress', function(e) {
   if( e.which === 13 )
       return false;
});
```

returning `false` from an event handler causes two things:

- .preventDefault() is called on the event object
- .stopPropagation() is called on the event object

that should stop the `return` from bubbling up to your `<form>` node, which in turn prevents the submit. So, it's actually enough to call `e.stopPropagation()` here.

Answer (score 1):

I would try doing the same thing but binding it with [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to the form. You can then return false, or whatever you need to do.

**EDIT:** I'm leaving this here, because it's useful. But I soon realized that not for this question, since I don't think you can track keypresses with this method. I blame this on just waking up and having not really touched JavaScript in awhile. Sorry for any confusion!