# Default action to execute when pressing enter in a form

Tags: jsf, action, default, form-submit, enter

I've got a jsf 1.2 form with two buttons and several input fields. The first button discards the entered values and repopulates the page with values from a db, the second button saves the entered values. The problem occurs when the user presses enter while the cursor is in one of the input fields, the form gets submitted and the action associated with the first button gets executed.

The code looks like this:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.reset}" value="Reset" />
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.save}" value="Save" />

<!-- h:datatable with several h:inputText elements -->
```

Is it possible to declare a specific button as the default action when pressing enter? Is this behaviour actually specified somewhere?

Comment: Trinidad provides such a functionality within it's form tag. [link](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_form.html)

Comment: Hi Jörn, I'd disable autosubmit for forms with just one input field. I guess you don't want the form to be submitted by pressing return in the field. - btw: see you at JAX this year?

Comment: Thomas: Is there an easy way to disable submit on enter (perhaps without javascript as in BalusCs answer)? And yes, I will be at Jax in Mainz.

Comment: Primefaces is also going to include a `DefaultCommand` component, just announced on the primefaces blog (http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1787).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

This is not specific to JSF. This is specific to HTML. The [HTML5 forms specification section 4.10.22.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission) basically specifies that the first occuring `<input type="submit">` element in the "tree order" in same `<form>` as the current input element in the HTML DOM tree will be invoked on enter press.

There are basically two workarounds:

- Use JavaScript to capture the enter key press and invoke the desired button.

  ```
    <h:form onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { document.getElementById('formid:saveid').click(); return false; }">
  ```

  If you have textareas in the form, you'd like to put the JS on all non-textarea input elements instead of on the form. See also [Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter/1977126#1977126).

  ---
- Swap the buttons in HTML and use CSS floats to swap them back.

  ```
    <div style="width: 100px; clear: both;">
        <h:commandButton action="#{bean.save}" value="Save" style="float: right;" />
        <h:commandButton action="#{bean.reset}" value="Reset" style="float: left;" />
    </div>
  ```

  It may only require some pixel finetuning. Of course put CSS in its own `.css` file; using `style` is poor practice, the above example is for brevity.

  ---

If you happen to use PrimeFaces, since 3.2 you can use [`<p:defaultCommand>`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/defaultcommand/basic.xhtml) to declaratively identify the button which should be invoked when pressing enter key within the form.

```
<h:form>
    <p:defaultCommand target="save" />
    ...
    <h:commandButton id="reset" action="#{bean.reset}" value="Reset" />
    <h:commandButton id="save" action="#{bean.save}" value="Save" />
</h:form>
```

It's under the covers using JavaScript for that which attaches a `keydown` listener to the parent `<h:form>` which in turn checks if the enter key is pressed in a non-textarea/button/link element, and then invokes `click()` on the target element. Basically the same as 1st mentioned workaround in this answer.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the javascript a bit to only execute on text input fields, otherwise pressing enter while any button has the focus would also execute the save action. The modified handler looks like this: `if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.target.nodeName == 'INPUT' && event.target.getAttribute('type') == 'text') { document.getElementById('form:saveButton').click(); return false; }`

Comment: I note that defaultCommand executes on keydown - is there a way to change it to keyup?  We are having a problem where our form is being submitted many times if the enter key is held down sometimes - not always.

Answer (score 10):

I found a way which is less hacky and works well. The idea is a hidden `commandButton`.

Unfortunately `display:none` style cannot be used because then the `commandButton` will be ignored. `visibility:hidden` is not good because it keeps the component's space reserved.

But we can fine tune the style so the size of its **visual appearance will be zero** with the following CSS:

```
.zeroSize {
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

**And now all it takes is:**

```
<h:commandButton value="" action="#{bean.save}" class="zeroSize" />
```

This will result in an invisible command button which according to the first-next-submit-button rule can be activated.

Comment: Doesn't this take focus when you use the tab button?

Comment: @JasperdeVries No, it does not because it is not visible (`visibility:hidden;`).

Comment: This solution IMO is better than the approved one, since it solves the precisely the problem the question was about with less effort.

Answer (score 5):

To hide elements you can use css: `style="visibility: hidden"`

To change the default action if you use primefaces,  you can use: `<p:defaultCommand target="yourButtonDefault" />`
For example:

```
<h:form id="form">

    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
        <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
        <p:inputText id="name" value="#{defaultCommandBean.text}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{defaultCommandBean.text}" id="display" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Button1" id="btn1" actionListener="#{defaultCommandBean.btn1Submit}" ajax="false"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Button2" id="btn2" actionListener="#{defaultCommandBean.btn2Submit}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Button3" id="btn3" actionListener="#{defaultCommandBean.btn3Submit}" />

    <p:defaultCommand target="btn3" />

</h:form>
```

Source: [Primefaces new component: DefaultCommand](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1787)

Comment: Use this in combination with the <p:focus> and you will rock!

Comment: Note that in case you want to **prevent** forms being submitted, make sure to remove all `p:defaultCommand` occurrences.

Comment: I note that defaultCommand executes on keydown - is there a way to change it to keyup? We are having a problem where our form is being submitted many times if the enter key is held down sometimes - not always.

Answer (score 3):

Following BalusC's recommendation to solve the problem using JavaScript, I wrote some jQuery code to do the job:

```
$(function(){
  $('form').on('keypress', function(event){
    if(event.which === 13 && $(event.target).is(':input')){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#save').trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/timbuethe/pen/AoKJj

Answer (score 3):

Ignore the ENTER key only in text input fields ([source](http://webcheatsheet.com/javascript/disable_enter_key.php)):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  function stopRKey(evt) { 
     var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
     var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
     if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;} 
  } 

  document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `h:commandLink` for the first button and style it with css like the `h:commandButton`.

For Example bootstraps `"btn btn-default"` look the same on commandLink and commandButton.