# JSF enter key not working to submit form when using p:commandLink

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I have the code below which is just an input box and an image for the p:commandLink. My problem is that when i press the enter key, the page is just refreshed and it doesn't get inside of my submit method. If i click the image instead of hitting the enter key, everything is fine. Also if i change the `p:commandLink` to a `p:commandButton` hitting the enter key works too, it's just that my image doesn't look right because a button is there.

How can i get the enter key to submit a form when i'm using a commandLink instead of a commandButton?

```
<h:form id="searchForm">
  <p:inputText id="searchBoxMember" value="#{searchBacking.anyWords}" />
  <p:watermark for="searchBoxMember" value="Search" />
  <p:commandLink styleClass="searchSubmitImage" ajax="false" action="#{searchBacking.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: This is more a HTML question than a JSF/Primefaces question. This can be rephrased as *I have a `<form>` with a link `<a>` and when I hit the Enter key it just refreshes but never executes the code from the link. When switching the link to a button `<input type="submit">` works as expected. How to make this work for a link as well as for a button?\*.

Comment: Now that you put it that way, is there a jsf component that uses `<input type="submit">` rather than `<button type="submit">`?

Comment: `<h:commandButton>` from `xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html`

Comment: @Andy `<p:commandButton>` also renders `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know but asked for a jsf component. Took his question literally. Now he has two options :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `<p:commandButton>` is actually rendering a `<button type="submit">`. I'm using Primefaces 3.2, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: No it won't make a difference. So in the end will you use `<p:commandButton>` or `<p:commandLink>` for this?

Comment: The reason it's making a difference (or at least i think it makes a difference) is because when i use `p:commandButton`, it uses an actual html button, while the `p:commandLink` does not use a button. I can style a `p:commandLink` as an image, but when i use `p:commandButton` my image looks like it's on top of a button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default action to execute when pressing enter in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form)

Answer (score 0):

In your field, you could try:

```
onKeyDown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {
  this.blur();
  setTimeout(function() {
      jquery or javascript code to target the link and issue a click event).click();
  }, 800);
}"
```