# h:commandButton with twitter bootstrap or other icon

Tags: jsf, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap css to style. To make icon buttons in it, the standard way is to use "i" tags.
`<button type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>`.
But I cant enter it within
   `<h:commandButton id="myid"><i class="icon-search"></i></h:commandButton>`
How can I add HTML within the rendered     `<h:commandButton>` ?

Answer (score 12):

You can add `<i class="icon-search"></i>` inside `h:commandLink`

Command link could be styled as button

```
<h:commandLink id="btnsearch"
    action="search.xhtml"
    styleClass="btn btn-default">
    <i class="icon-search"></i> Search
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: I found that using this solution, since it renders an anchor-tag, the form does not submit on enter. Other than that it's a good solution.

Comment: If you use this solution combined with balusC's answer in this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/jsf-default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form
The enter key will work too.

Answer (score 1):

I just used a hack for now. It's like this (I hid the h:commandButton and added a new submit button).

```
<h:form id="myFrm" >
   <h:inputText id="search" value="#{user.name}"></h:inputText>
   <h:commandButton id="btnsearch" action="search.xhtml" style="display: none"></h:commandButton>
   <button  type="submit" id="myFrm:btnsearch" name="myFrm:btnsearch"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
</h:form>
```