# Is there a limitation on JSF <h:commandButton> with font-awesome icon

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am working on JSF 2.2

Font awesome 'fonts' work with html buttons of type submit. Since a `<h:commandButton>` is exactly that; a button of type submit, why can't i add fon't awesome to it?

**Is it a limitation of `<h:commandButton>` in jsf?**

**My code:**

```
  <h:commandButton 
      styleClass="btn btn-default" 
      action="#{myBean.name}" >

      <i class="fa fa-trash" style="font-size: 1em"> </i>

  </h:commandButton>
```

I know that i can use `<h:commandLink>` instead as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895869/jsf-hcommandbutton-with-twitter-bootstrap-icon). But when i am making a button, its not intuitive to make a link instead, which is what `<h:commandLink>` appears as.

Comment: Can you add a font-awesome icon on a plain html button? Since that is what the jsf button renders into. If you can, post the required html and then we'll try to port it to a jsf button

Comment: have you tried BootsFaces?  it includes font awesome support like `<b:commandButton ... iconAwesome="trash" />` https://www.bootsfaces.net/

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35506024/59087