# <p:commandButton>'s action listener not firing with attribute type="button"

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton

Is it possible to fire action,actionListener of a `<p:commandButton>` with attribute `type="button"`. I have a requirement where in a form there are text boxes and command buttons. If I press enter in any text box then `commandButton` is invoked. So I change all command buttons type to "button". Now problem I am facing that command button's action, actionListener not firing.I want to solve it with out using java script. Also I read this  [**This Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/jsf-default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form). Can any one tell me where I should edit or change to get expected output. Thanks.

Comment: by text box do you mean inputText or inputTextArea?

Comment: @Damian: yes I mean `<p:inputText>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `type="button"` is the wrong solution to prevent enter key from submitting the form. It basically changes the submit button to a dead button which does not submit the form and is only useful for attaching JavaScript `onclick` and likes. You're simply facing the consequences of this wrong solution. You should not try to fix it, but take a step back and solve the initial problem the right way.

One of the ways is:

```
<h:form onkeydown="return event.keyCode != 13">
```

Or, more generically, with jQuery, which skips textareas from the restriction:

```
$(document).on("keydown", ":input:not[textarea]", function(event) {
    return event.keyCode != 13;
});
```

Note: jQuery is already bundled in PrimeFaces, you do *not* need to install any scripts separately. Also note that you really can't go around JavaScript here. Even more, PrimeFaces/ajax components rely on JavaScript and wouldn't work anyway without JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already read your reply in above given link in question. But I am trying to solve it with out using javaScript. so is it possible?

Comment: No. This restriction is also not making any sense.