# JSF commandButton executed upon Enter on random form field

Tags: jsf, input, actionlistener, enter, commandbutton

I have a form with several buttons and a link that says "Delete user data". Upon click on the link, a confirmation popup shows before any action takes place. Here is the code for this:

```
<p:confirmDialog closable="false"
    header="#{bundle['remove.user.data']}"
    message="#{bundle['remove.user.data.text']}"
    severity="alert" widgetVar="deleteUserPopup">
    <h:commandButton
        actionListener="#{userBean.deleteUserData}"
        value="#{bundle['yes']}" immediate="true"
        onclick="deleteUserPopup.hide()">
            <f:attribute name="userId"
                value="#{userBean.user.id}" />
            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@all" />
    </h:commandButton>      
    <h:commandButton value="#{bundle['no']}"
        onclick="deleteUserPopup.hide()" type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>

<div>
    <h:commandLink>
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle['remove.user']}" />
        <h:graphicImage name="remove.png" library="img"
            title="#{bundle['remove.user']}" />
        <f:ajax event="click"
            onevent="deleteUserPopup.show()" />
    </h:commandLink>
</div>
```

In the form, I have a lot of fields, but it's the text fields that are problematic, because when a user enters text in it and hits on Enter, the method `deleteUserData` is called immediately (**without confirmation popup**). Here is the code of one two fields for example:

```
<div>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:column>
            <h:inputText
                value="#{userBean.user.lastName}" id="userLastName" />
            <h:message for="userLastName" styleClass="warning" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:inputText
                value="#{userBean.user.firstName}" id="userFirstName" />
                <h:message for="userFirstName" styleClass="warning" />
        </h:column>
    </h:panelGrid>
</div>
```

All of the above code (2 divs and a confirm dialog) comes inside of a `<h:form>`
So, I don't get it, why on Enter the action listener of the command button is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal HTML behavior, general, the firstnext input type="submit" relative to the current input element will be invoked on enter press. Full answer on this page: [Default action to execute when pressing enter in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/jsf-default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form)

Comment: Hello and thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, none of the suggested solutions worked out - neither the JS capture of the enter key, nor swapping the buttons in HTML, nor even adding a new first button with visibility:hidden. I think the problem here is not that a firstnext input is being submitted, but another one.Can you suggest another workaround?

Comment: Did you try this <p:defaultCommand target="btn_to_enter" /> ? You can use the p:defaultCommand with id to your Button to define what happens when the Enter key is pressed

Comment: Maybe simple workaround :<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $("form").bind("keypress", function(e) {
              if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                 return false;
              }
           });
        });
</script>

Comment: and also some page with example for rich faces http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/11/06/disable-enter-form-submit-fix-inputnumberspinner/