# JSF + primefaces spinner ajax invoking other submits

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using ajax in spinner to call some action in backing bean.

this is my code:

```
<b:panel>
    <p:dataTable id="orderDataTable" var="order" value="#{orderViewBean.orders}"
                 widgetVar="ordersDataTable" tableStyle="table-layout: auto;">
        <p:column headerText="Created" filterBy="#{order.creationDate}" filterStyle="display: none"
                  filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{order.creationDate}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Created By" filterBy="#{order.createdBy}" filterStyle="display: none"
                  filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{order.createdBy}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <b:panelGrid colSpans="4,4,4">
        <b:commandButton action="#{orderViewBean.previousPage}" value="Previous"
                         look="primary" process="@this:uploadOrderDataPanel" styleClass="pull-left"
                         disabled="#{!orderViewBean.page.hasPrevious()}" type="submit">
            <p:ajax immediate="true" update=":companyOrdersForm"/>
        </b:commandButton>
        <b:row>
            <div class="text-center">
                <h:outputLabel value="Page"/>
                <p:spinner value="#{orderViewBean.currentPage}" size="3"
                           min="#{orderViewBean.page.totalPages > 0 ? 1 : 0}"
                           max="#{orderViewBean.page.totalPages}">
                    <p:ajax listener="#{orderViewBean.changePageAjax}"
                            update="@form" process="@this" immediate="true"/>
                </p:spinner>
                <h:outputLabel value="Of"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{orderViewBean.page.totalPages}"/>
            </div>
        </b:row>
        <b:commandButton action="#{orderViewBean.nextPage}" value="Next"
                         look="primary" process="@this:uploadOrderDataPanel" styleClass="pull-right"
                         disabled="#{!orderViewBean.page.hasNext()}" type="submit">
            <p:ajax immediate="true" update=":companyOrdersForm"/>
        </b:commandButton>
    </b:panelGrid>
</b:panel>
```

When I put some number into spinner and hit enter, then changePageAjax is invoked (this is ok) and also orderViewBean.previousPage (this is not ok). Can I avoid invoking other actions?

Comment: what are the b: tags? Also PrimeFaces? Or custom/composite components?

Comment: Hint: PrimeFaces has a Bootstrap theme.

Comment: @BalusC thanks, I know about that theme, I'm currenty using it, but some components are better in bootsfaces. I tried to replace bootsfaces buttons with primefaces, but I have still same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Add a `partialSubmit="true"` attribute on the relevant ajax tags.. From the PF documentation:

> PartialSubmit reduces network traffic by only adding the partially processed components to the ajax request post. For big pages with many input components, partialSubmit is extremely useful as it leads to more lightweight requests. Compare the Post Data displayed by the logger for the difference.

*See also*:

- http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/partialSubmit.xhtml

Comment: Then explain more clearly what your issue is, with screenshots of network traffic etc.... Ahhhh wait... you hit ENTER.... welll... Then the default action is executed, which normallly is the first button... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form

Comment: Ok so basically, I'm using spinner for my custom paginator. I'd like to be able to write custom page number to this spinner, hit enter and then invoke action which will return requested page number.