# Primefaces onkeyPress triggerevent

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm doing Primefaces 5.1. In my page use two commandButton Add,Edit button and username Text field. When I press enter in username text field script to perform editbutton click want perform.But it will perform addButton click.I try below code:

```
<h:head>
<script>
function callEvent(evnt)
{
if(event.keyCode==13)
{
$('editbutton').trigger('click');
}
</script>

</h:head>
<h:form>
<p:inputText id="userNameField" onkeyPress="callerEvent(event)"/>
.....
....
<p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" action="#{user.saveButton}"/>
<p:commandButton id="editbutton" value="Edit" action="#{user.editButton}"/>
</h:form>
```

When I press enter in textfield it will not perform editbutton only trigger with first button that is addbutton.If I change position of button i.e editbutton is first it will perform editbutton.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
<h:form id="user-form">
```

and:

```
<script>
   function callEvent(event) {
      if(event.keyCode==13) {
         $('#user-form\\:editbutton').click();
         return false;
      }
</script>
```

**See also:**

[Default action to execute when pressing enter in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form)

Comment: DefaultCommand is triiger work when I press any textbox to press enter key.But I want to specify textbox press enter to triggerWork

Comment: I try it (Primefaces 5.1) but same it only trigger first button(saveButton) performed

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:
1. function name is `callEvent`, but you are using `callerEvent` with text field keyPress event.
2. id selector for editbutton is not correct to get element.

You can simply do it with jQuery like selector (ends-with) as following:

```
<p:inputText id="userNameField" />

$("input[id$='userNameField']").on('keypress', function(event) {
    var keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if(keycode == '13')
        $("input[id$='editbutton']").get(0).click();    
});
```