# Enter event to an input box invokes button click action

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

I have an input box which invokes a button action when Enter key is pressed.

```
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.fname}" id="name" onkeydown="callClickEvent(event);"></h:inputText>


**Js function is**
--------------

function callClickEvent(event){
                 if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which==13) {
                 document.getElementById('dataForm:btnA').click();
               }

        }
```

**In my xhtml i have two button**

```
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.actionPerform}" id="btnA""/>
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.updateAction}" id="btnB"/>
```

now the problem is , this code runs fine in chrome and firefox but not working as expected in IE9;

in IE 9 , when  I  hit enter key it invokes  both buttons action.

suggested solution in stack overflow were:
(1)  add type ="button"
(2) add e.preventDefault() inside javascipt function.

when i add type="button",  action method dosen't invoke when i click second button.

and when i add e.preventDefault(), it does'nt let me type anything side input box.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have that `callClickEvent()` in first place? It's the cause of all that trouble and doesn't look useful at all. Get rid of it and take a step back and reformulate a question for that particular problem for which you [incorrectly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) thought that `callClickEvent()` would be the right solution.

Comment: Hi Balu,  it is onkeydown  to trap enter key event.

Comment: it seems ,  enter key down submitting my form thus invoking second button action.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: @Farhan: no he can't. You cannot put  non-parsed JSF code in a jsfiddle. And at the OP: **Why** do you want to trap the enter key event?

Comment: Hi Kukeltje,  text box will  accept some string and just  by hitting Enter  key ,I want to invoke an action rather than clicking a button .

Comment: Is this a duplicate then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form

Comment: Hi,
     when i add  event.preventDefault(), then i am not able to type anything inside text box. 

function callClickEvent(event){
                 event.preventDefault();
                 if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which==13) {
                 document.getElementById('dataForm:btnA').click();
               }

        }