# Pressing enter does not hit the expected search button via p:defaultCommand

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use primefaces  but its not producing expected result. My code snippet is below

```
<h:form id="searchForm" styleClass="searchForm">    
     <p:panelGrid columns="3">
         <p:commandButton id="left-overlay-btn" value="" styleClass="xschnapp-search-filter-menu" />
         <p:inputText required="true" placeholder="#{cc.attrs.searchTip}" value="#{cc.attrs.queryProperty}" />
         <p:commandButton value="&#160;" id="searchButton" action="#{cc.attrs.searchAction}" styleClass="xschnapp-search-action" />
     </p:panelGrid>
     <p:defaultCommand target="searchButton">
</h:form>
```

In Above code, when I press enter then it hits the first column button and not the expected search even after using primefaces p:defaultCommand.

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1787

Someone adviced me to use javascript to manually click search button, thats also failing. Perhaps due to my weak javascript knowledge. Below is code snippet with javascript and that also hit first column button instead of desired search button

```
<h:form id="searchForm" styleClass="searchForm" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {document.getElementById('searchButton').click(); return false}">    
        <p:panelGrid columns="3">
            <p:commandButton id="left-overlay-btn" value="" styleClass="xschnapp-search-filter-menu" />
            <p:inputText required="true" placeholder="#{cc.attrs.searchTip}" value="#{cc.attrs.queryProperty}" />
            <p:commandButton value="&#160;" id="searchButton" action="#{cc.attrs.searchAction}" styleClass="xschnapp-search-action" />
        </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Can somebody please help me.

Comment: Why did you not just improve your original question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330347/hitting-enter-goes-to-wrong-button

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, thanks for your suggestion. I'll keep in mind for the next time.

Comment: So either remove the other one or this one... take your pick...

Comment: other deleted. Any idea, why getDocumentById(form:searchButton) is showing null ? or whats wrong in javascript call ?

Comment: Check the `id` of your button in the resulting html : according to what you provided it is not `form:searchButton`.

Comment: I have tried all possible combination getDocumentById('form:searchButton'), getDocumentById('searchForm:searchButton'), getDocumentById('searchButton'), getDocumentById('form.searchButton') and still the result is null

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem defining global hotkey for my enterprise site. The aproach which worked for me is:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:hotkey bind="Enter" update="msg" actionListener="#{yourBean.yourSearchfunction}"/>
    <p:remoteCommand name="search" actionListener="#{yourBean.yourSearchfunction}" update="msg"/>
    //Your code
</h:form>
<h:outputScript>
$(':input').bind('keydown', 'Enter', function () {
    search();
    return false;
});
</h:outputScript>
```

With this code regardless where your cursor stays it will start your search function on pressing enter. Maybe you want it a bit more finegrained then you can remove the p:hotkey component to only use to start your search function if the cursor is inside a input field.

The javascript is needed because the p:hotkey component works everywhere except if the cursor stays inside an input field. So you bind your remote comand to the enter event inside every inputfield in the view.

Comment: I tried this approach, its not working :( Because I only have the id of searchButton. Search Action is associated with this button already by composite-elements.