# Call a method in bean class from inputtext tag in jsf on press of enter key

Tags: jsf

Jsf file having inputtext field.After entering value in the field and pressing enter,it should perform the action in command button(nextButton) i.e- call Action() in BackingBean.java

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax">

    <ui:define id="content" name="page-content">
    <h:inputText id="Number" value="#{BackinBean.Id}"/>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define id="contentfooter" name="page-content_footer">

        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:commandButton id="nextButton" value="Next"
                        action="#{BackinBean.Action}" styleClass="btn"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ui:define>
```

Bean class-BackingBean.java has

```
    public Action(){..........}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no `form` tag and your commandButton has no `process` attribute.

Study this definitive guide: [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is, you will need to capture the keycode and check if it is enter event (keycode = 13 ) and trigger click event on the button you desire which will submit the form and invoke the associated backing bean action method. Please see [Default action to execute when pressing enter in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485851/default-action-to-execute-when-pressing-enter-in-a-form)