# Non-JS way to stop "enter" in <input> from submitting form?

Tags: css, html

I have a form with a `<textarea required>`, `<input type="checkbox">`, `<input type="text">`, and `<button type="submit">`.

It's all fancified with jQuery, so that if you're in the text-input, or tab to the checkbox, and hit Enter, I catch that and preventDefault so the form doesn't submit.

But I want the form to be equally sensible for people who aren't running Javascript.  Surely there is some markup or CSS to indicate that a given form element shouldn't cause form submission?

Comment: What? What's sensible about making Enter not submit a form when it works like that everywhere else in the browser (and wider operating system)? Please leave default form behaviours alone.

Comment: It's a feedback form. The textarea is required (the feedback!), the name/email/do-you give-permission-for-me-to-share-your-feedback parts are optional and off to the side.  "Enter" when in the textarea doesn't do anything but add a linebreak (default behaviour!). I don't personally expect that hitting "enter" -- *only* while in the "name" field -- submits the *feedback*.  Do we have evidence about average users?

Comment: In today's browsers and operating systems, pressing Enter in a single-line text field submits the form, pressing Enter in a textarea puts a newline in and doesn't submit the form. This is completely standard behaviour and, whether you agree with it or not, it's more unexpected when you don't behave like the standard.

Comment: (Or evidence about googlebot/mouse-only/keyboard-only/visual/aural/etc. users.  With all sorts of UAs. I'm hoping to be able to support everyone well, as best I can.)

Comment: @bobince (You have a lot of people to argue against, even if your choice is best. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter , and several similar questions.)

Comment: Later I'll ask on SO about the tradeoffs of the different behaviours (unless there's an equivalent question already).

Answer (score 0):

Only javascript accepts events.

You must validate using server-side when you don't have javascript actived.

Comment: This is not about validating (I do that server-side), but about providing a nice user experience (helping the user avoid accidentally sending off a POST request and loading another page when they didn't intend to).