# Ajax operation returning true in always

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use ajax to do some validations. Its calling a method from my MVC3 controller but its return true whether the controller returns true or false. The alert always is displayed.

ClientChoices/HasJobInProgress

```
 public Boolean HasJobInProgress(int clientId)
        {
            return false;
            //return _proxy.GetJobInProgress(clientId);
        }
```

Jquery.Ajax

```
 $("#saveButton").click(function() {
        var hasCurrentJob =  
            $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgress", "ClientChoices")/',
            data: { id: @Model.ClientId },
            success: function(data){
                return data;
            }
            });
        if (hasCurrentJob) {
            alert("The current clients has a job in progress. No changes can be saved until current job completes");
        } 
    });
```

***SOLUTION***

```
$("#saveButton").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgress", "ClientChoices")/',
            data: { id: '@Model.ClientId' },
            success: function(data){
                showMsg(data);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });

    function showMsg(hasCurrentJob) {
          if (hasCurrentJob.toString()=="True") {
               alert("The current clients has a job in progress. No changes can be saved until current job completes");
          } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX calls are async and your return data will not set the value of `hasCurrentJob` and it is a return to the success callback. See below on how you can show alert based on `data`.

```
    $("#saveButton").click(function() {
        //var hasCurrentJob
            $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgress", "ClientChoices")/',
            data: { id: @Model.ClientId },
            success: function(data){
                showMsg(data);
            }
            });

    });

    function showMsg(hasCurrentJob) {
          if (hasCurrentJob === 'true') {
               alert("The current clients has a job in progress. No changes can be saved until current job completes");
          } 
    }
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working  at all. The alert doesn't display in either condition.

Comment: @atbyrd Do you see any script error? Can you set an alert inside showMsg function and see if it is getting called? Also `alert(data)` to check what value is being returned.

Comment: After rebuilding and forcing ie to reload it works. but with the same result as before.

Comment: when i say same results: i mean its alerts in both conditions

Comment: ahh I see, probably you are getting a string and not boolean. Try `if (hasCurrentJob === 'true') {`

Comment: That didn't work either but did lead me to a solution. Will post above. Thanks for your persistence.

Comment: @atbyrd Try using `if (hasCurrentJob === 'True')` instead of .toString. because 'True' != 'true'

Comment: do you know how I can make this prevent the button from submitting?

Comment: SO is Q/A website. You can look for similar question or post that as a new question.. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/895231/297641 It is basically event.preventDefault() that you need to add. Also pass event object to the function as `$("#saveButton").click(function(event) {`