# Stop form from submitting , Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, preventdefault

I'm trying to stop my form from submitting if a validation fails. I tried following this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/895231/297641) but I doesn't work for me. What am I missing?

```
<input id="saveButton" type="submit" value="Save" />
<input id="cancelButton" type="button" value="Cancel" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgress", "ClientChoices")/',
                data: { id: '@Model.ClientId' },
                success: function (data) {
                    showMsg(data, e);
                },
                cache: false
            });
        });
    });
    $("#cancelButton").click(function () {
        window.location = '@Url.Action("list", "default", new { clientId = Model.ClientId })';
    });
    $("[type=text]").focus(function () {
        $(this).select();
    });
    function showMsg(hasCurrentJob, sender) {
        if (hasCurrentJob == "True") {
            alert("The current clients has a job in progress. No changes can be saved until current job completes");
            if (sender != null) {
                sender.preventDefault();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: which function in the above code is stopping the form from submitting? What is showMsg function doing? Why are you using sender.preventDefault(); Is sender argument an event? preventDefault() is used to stop the normal behaviour of an element upon some event like click etc.

Comment: sender is referring to e : event

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Again, AJAX is async. So the showMsg function will be called only after success response from the server.. and the form submit event will not wait until AJAX success.

Move the `e.preventDefault();` as first line in the click handler.

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent from submitting the form.
      ...
```

See below code,

> I want it to be allowed HasJobInProgress == False

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgress", "ClientChoices")/',
            data: { id: '@Model.ClientId' },
            success: function (data) {
                showMsg(data);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });
});
$("#cancelButton").click(function () {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("list", "default", new { clientId = Model.ClientId })';
});
$("[type=text]").focus(function () {
    $(this).select();
});
function showMsg(hasCurrentJob) {
    if (hasCurrentJob == "True") {
        alert("The current clients has a job in progress. No changes can be saved until current job completes");
        return false;
    } else {
       $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: won't this prevent it in all situation?

Comment: on what condition you want the event to be allowed. You probably need to prevent it from submitting, then wait for AJAX response and trigger submit manually.

Comment: I want it to be allowed  HasJobInProgress == False

Comment: @Vega thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you ...

Answer (score 15):

use this too :

```
if(e.preventDefault) 
   e.preventDefault(); 
else 
   e.returnValue = false;
```

> Becoz **e.preventDefault()** is not supported in IE( some versions ). In IE it is **e.returnValue = false**

Comment: in case you use jQuery you can safely use `e.preventDefault()`. jQuery will take care for the x-browser compatibility.

Comment: From the [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) API: "Returning false from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`."  It goes on to say: "A `false` value can also be passed for the handler as a shorthand for `function(){ return false; }`"

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below.  **e.preventDefault() was added**. This removes the default event action for the form.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
       $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgress", "ClientChoices")/',
            data: { id: '@Model.ClientId' },
            success: function (data) {
                showMsg(data, e);
            },
            cache: false
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Also,  you mentioned you wanted the form to not submit under the premise of validation, but I see no code validation here?

**Here is an example of some added validation**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
      /* put your form field(s) you want to validate here, this checks if your input field of choice is blank */
    if(!$('#inputID').val()){ 
       e.preventDefault(); // This will prevent the form submission
     } else{
        // In the event all validations pass. THEN process AJAX request.
       $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgress", "ClientChoices")/',
            data: { id: '@Model.ClientId' },
            success: function (data) {
                showMsg(data, e);
            },
            cache: false
       });
     }


    });
 });
```

Comment: I'm not actually validating a field. This ajax portion of the code calls a method that checks if a job for the client is already in progress. I don't want to allow multiple jobs for the same client to be enqueue.

Answer (score 3):

A different approach could be

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckData() {
    //you may want to check something here and based on that wanna return true and false from the         function.
    if(MyStuffIsokay)
     return true;//will cause form to postback to server.
    else
      return false;//will cause form Not to postback to server
    }
    </script>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveEmployee", "Employees", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EmployeeDetailsForm" }))
    {
    .........
    .........
    .........
    .........
    <input type="submit" value= "Save Employee" onclick="return CheckData();"/>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a JQuery code for Preventing Submit

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
            if (radioButtonValue !== "0") {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```