# event.preventDefault in IE 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am submitting a form and I want to prevent the submit action until I do a few other actions like showing a progress bar for file uploads. I set up this code based on SO questions such as [event.preventDefault() function not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fileform").submit(function(e){
        if(!e) e = window.event;
        if (e.preventDefault){
            // Firefox, Chrome
            e.preventDefault();
        }else{
            // Internet Explorer
            e.returnValue = false;
        }

        // other code
    }
}
```

Everything works fine in Firefox and Chrome; the submit action is prevented, the progress bar appears and then the form is submitted when I tell it to. However, in IE 10, the first condition of the if statement is executed and the form seems to be trying to submit (IE 10's submit bubbles show up). Why is the first condition being executed?

Does IE 10 support preventDefault() where IE 8 and 9 didn't? If so, how do I properly handle preventing the form submit action in IE 8, 9, 10 that won't interfere with Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do the below, jQuery has already done the cross browser job for you.

```
$("#fileform").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // other code
});
```

Comment: When I use this code, nothing changes. Firefox and Chrome still work fine, but my progress bar doesn't appear in IE (the IE form submit bubbles appear).

Comment: Nevermind, you're right. The event is normalized in jQuery and e.preventDefault() does work as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try also to put the following:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

after

```
e.preventDefault();
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

If you read: [Stop form from submitting , Using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092580/stop-form-from-submitting-using-jquery)

you'll see:

```
Becoz e.preventDefault() is not supported in IE. In IE it is e.returnValue = false
```

The modified code:

```
   $("#fileform").submit(function(e){
        if(!e) e = window.event;

         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();

        // other code, do something here
        return true; // or false if something goes wrong
    }
```

Comment: Using `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();` shows no change.