# Images tremble on animate

Tags: jquery

I wrote a little script to animate elements of a list on mousewheel scroll

HTML

```
<div id="scroll">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/egMFpfq.jpg')"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/qjmCv5g.jpg')"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/egMFpfq.jpg')"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/qjmCv5g.jpg')"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/egMFpfq.jpg')"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$.fn.scroll = function () {
var $this = $(this);
var $list = $(this).find('ul');
var $lis = $list.find('li');
var count = $lis.length;
var direction,
currentSlidePosition;

$this.addClass('scroll');
$list.addClass('slides-list');
$lis.addClass('slide');
$lis.filter(':first').addClass('current');
$lis.filter(':not(:first)').addClass('past');

var scrollHeight = $lis.eq(0).height();

function gotoSlide(direction) {
    currentSlidePosition = $lis.filter('.current').index();

    if ((direction === 1 && currentSlidePosition === 0) || (direction === -1 && currentSlidePosition === count - 1)) {
        return;
    }

    $lis.removeClass('current');
    $lis.eq(currentSlidePosition - direction).removeClass('past prev').addClass('current');
    $lis.filter('.current').prevAll().addClass('prev');
    $lis.filter('.current').nextAll().addClass('past');
    console.log($list.scrollTop())
    $list.animate({
        scrollTop: (direction === -1) ? $list.scrollTop()+scrollHeight : $list.scrollTop()-scrollHeight
    }, {
        duration: 600
    });
}

$this.on('mouseenter', function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        if ($list.is(':animated')) {

            return;
        }

        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
            direction = 1; //up
        } else {                
            direction = -1; //down
        }

        gotoSlide(direction);
    });
});
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#scroll').scroll();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5unj2wu/15/

but on every scroll background images tremble and twitch and it looks ugly.  Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scrolling is competing with the browser's own scrolling, so you need to tell it not to attempt to scroll itself. You can achieve this with `event.preventDefault()` in your event handler:

```
$this.bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
```

Note that even though older IE versions don't natively support `preventDefault()`, jQuery [provides this function for you](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on those browsers, so this is cross-browser safe.

http://jsfiddle.net/m5unj2wu/17/

Comment: @ParagBhayani yes it will, jQuery handles that for you by sanitizing the event object. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17184287/1469259

Answer (score 3):

return `false`

```
   $this.bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        if ($list.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        ...
        return false;
    });
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/m5unj2wu/21/**

`return false` from within a jQuery event handler is effectively the same as calling both `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this code above your function and it will work

```
$('#scroll').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function() {
    return false
});
```

This flickering is happening because you are registering your function on div on scroll event, so When you mouse scroll on element it does 2 thing 1) Calls your function 2) Scrolls down div which is default browser behaviour

So here we are disabling the browser's default behavior for scrolling the div

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5unj2wu/16/)