# Stop IE10 Submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, internet-explorer, submit

I have a form that is submitting some data to an external service. It work's in Chrome but the form keeps submitting in IE10. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184253/event-preventdefault-in-ie-10) post but the solution is not working.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$('#scanUrl').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();     
});
```

And then I am using `jquery-1.11.3.min.js` and my form looks like this:

```
<form style="margin-left:10%;" id="scanUrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="urlHolder" style="color: white; font-size: medium;">URL to Scan:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="urlHolder" style="width: 40%;">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Scan</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="helpButton">Help</button>
</form>
```

So I have tried many things (in no specific order):

1. `event.stopPropagation();`
2. `if(!event) event = window.event;`
3. `event.returnValue = false;`
4. `.click()` instead of `.submit()`
5. jquery 1.7 (older version of jquery) I know that 1.x supports IE6+ and 2.x supports IE9+. So I should be able to use 2.x but for safety I am using 1.x

Why is it submitting in IE10?

Comment: one possibility is an error being thrown before this code even fires and the preventDefault and submit handler never get activated. Any errors in console?

Comment: @Nathan is already in OP code

Comment: @charlietfl Yup I realized that too late! Just removed it.

Comment: @charlietfl Okay, so why would it be an error before the code even fires?

Comment: any number of reasons that may not have anything to do with this code block... are errors thrown in console? When an event isn't prevented like this it is typically a result of a script blocking error.

Comment: When I turn on network capturing, i see that it is hitting everything just like in Chrome. And I do not see anything in the Console. Also, when I put a breakpoint just inside the submit, it is not hitting the breakpoint. Idk if it's b/c I'm an IE noob or IE just hates me.

Comment: IE hates everyone...oops...other way around

Comment: Another thing that ie is a lot fussier about is invalid html. If there is anything invalid around that form can do this same thing also

Comment: Yeah, I've put my HTML into the w3c validator and it comes back with no errors. Just two info messages: `Info: The Content-Type was text/html. Using the HTML parser.` and `Info: Using the schema for HTML with SVG 1.1, MathML 3.0, RDFa 1.1, and ITS 2.0 support.`

Comment: any element ID duplication going on? Probably not, validator would have caught it

Comment: Nope. The HTML portion is small. It is a small application overall.

Comment: Bit of a short term hack but try changing SCan button to type = button and bind this code to clcik handler on that button and see what happens. The submit shouldn't trigger

Comment: What about `$(document).ready(function()`, would that have to do with anything?

Comment: Absolutely yes.  if form isn't there when this codes big problem....Oooo   also get rid of `async: false` is deprecated in modern browsers and really bad practice. It might even be the problem

Comment: Okay, the first part isn't an issue. Just checking. But you may be right with `async: false`, I added that for temporary use.

Comment: I changed the button to this `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="scanUrl" type="button">Scan</button>` but it did not work if that was what you were saying. I also took out `async:false` but that did not do anything either.

Comment: down vote explanation?

Comment: Problem could be narrowed down quite a bit. Start removing parts that may be irrelevant to the problem, such as everything in the submit callback other than event.preventDefault.

Comment: Okay, will do. How does down voting help me recognize this issue?

Comment: The purpose of the downvote wasn't to help you recognize the issue, it was to indicate quality.

Comment: I just edited the post. Better?

Comment: Do you have id="submit" anywhere on your page?

Comment: No it isn't anywhere in the code.

Comment: I can't recreate your problem in IE11 http://jsfiddle.net/w06w1ekz/

Comment: I tried the same thing in my code and the message is not appearing. The issue must be somewhere else in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pure JS code

```
var form = document.getElementById('scanUrl');
if (form.addEventListener){
    form.addEventListener('submit', handler, false);
} else if (element.attachEvent){
    form.attachEvent('onsubmit', handler);
} else {
    form ['onsubmit'] = handler;
}

function handler(event){
    var e = event ? event : window.event;
    if(e.prevnetDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else { 
        e.returnValue = false;
   }     
}
```

Answer (score -2):

event.preventDefault() is correct and works.
However, other lines in your full code may be confliting.
Try to isolate this fragment in another HTML document. This works for me.