# jquery popup div and update mysql record

Tags: php, jquery

First time poster! Apologies for the large about of code.

The plan is to have a list of users and on clicking on each user a div popup will appear allowing changes to the users details.

Rather than the popup closing when the record is updated I'd like the popup to remain open and show the new details.

At the moment I can open the popup and edit the form without the popup closing. As soon as I add the following the form closes on submit.

```
$( "#popup > #skills" ).load( "popup_u_skills.php?uid=" + uid );
```

If I pass don't pass a variable in the url then the popup stays open. The BIG problem I have is that I need to variable to be passed to get the users information from my DB.

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // show popup
    $(".showpopup").click(function() {

        // user id variable
        var uid = $(this).attr( "uid" );

        $("#popup").fadeIn();
        $( "#popup > #details" ).load( "popup_u_details.php?uid=" + uid ).show();
        //$( "#popup > #skills" ).load( "popup_u_skills.php?uid=" + uid );


        // close popup
        $(".closepopup").click(function() {

            $("#popup").fadeOut();

        }); 

        // open inner options within popup
        $(".open_inner_popup").click(function() {

            var inneropt = $(this).attr( "option" );

            $( "#details, #skills, #history" ).hide();

            $.get( "pop_u_skills.php", { uid : uid } );

            $( "#"+inneropt ).show();

        }); 

        // if change of skill
        $("#chg_skill").click(function(event){

            // use gloabel uid variable from openpopup
            var user = uid;
            // set array variable           
            var selected = new Array();

            // foreach checkbox cheked pushed into array
            $("input:checkbox[name=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
               selected.push($(this).val());
            });

                // prevent form action
                event.preventDefault();

                // post selected array and uid to php page
                $.post( 
                    "run_php.php",
                    { name: selected, uid: user },

                        function(data) {
                            $('#stage').show();
                            $('#stage').html("Saved!" + data);
                        });

                });

    // end open popup
    });

// end dom
});
</script>
<style>
#popup {
    width:400px;
    padding:10px;
    display:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px #EEE;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 0px #EEE;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index:1;
}

.closepopup {
    color:#FF0000;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#stage {
    display:none;
    color:#009900;
    }

#details, #skills, #history {
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?
$uid = date("H:s:i");
?>
<div id="overlay">

<div class="showpopup" uid="<? echo $uid; ?>"><a href="#">Popup</a></div>

    <div id="popup">
    <a href="#" class="closepopup">x</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="open_inner_popup" option="details">Details</a> <a href="#" class="open_inner_popup" option="skills">Skills</a> <a href="#" class="open_inner_popup" option="history">History</a>

        <div id="details"><? include "popup_u_details.php"; ?></div>

        <div id="skills"><? include "popup_u_skills.php"; ?></div>

        <div id="history">History</div>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**POPUP_U_SKILLS.PHP**

```
<div id="stage">&nbsp;</div>
<? echo $_GET["uid"]; ?>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <p>Option 1
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1">
      </p>
      <p>
        Option 2
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2">
      </p>
      <p>
        Option 3
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3">
    </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="chg_skill" id="chg_skill" value="Update">
      </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop form from submitting , Using Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092580/stop-form-from-submitting-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

After re-visiting jquery I have discovered the answer to my problem. Quite simple really.

To keep the popup div open on clicking a submit button within it I needed to include the code below within the submit function. e.g.

```
$(".submitwithinpopup").click(function() {

Do stuff...

// don't close popup afterwards
return false;

});
```