# Display php echo to a html div using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I want to display my echo text generated by php on to a seperate html page, for which i tried jquery and it didn't work.
Please don't block this question, because i refered to all the previous posts related to this kind of problem, but nothing really worked for me.

Here is the code
HTML

```
<form id="register-form" action="http://localhost/Exercises/media/index.php" method="post" role="form" >
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="firstname" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Firts name" value="">             
     <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" value="">
     <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
     <input type="text" name="dob" id="username" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="D-O-B">
     <input type="text" name="location" id="location" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Location">
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
     <input type="text" name="email2" id="email2" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Email">
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
     <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-Enter Password">

     <input type="submit" name="reg" id="reg" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now" style="background: #1AB188; border: 0px; border-radius: 3px;">
</form>
    <div id = "test"> </div><!--where i expect my php echo data to be displayed-->
```

JS

```
function getpage(sign_up) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://localhost/Exercises/media/index.php",
    data: {page: sign_up},
    success: function(data) {
        $('#test').html(data.msg);
    }
});
};
```

PHP

```
<?php

//json array to store echo messages foe ajax
$result = array(
                'un_limit' => 'the maximum limit for username/firstname/lastname is 25 characters',
                'pw_length' => 'Your Password must be between 8 and 30 characters long!',
                'pw_match' => 'Your password do not match',
                'all_fields' => 'Please fill in all the fields',
                'em_alrdy' => 'E-mail already used!',
                'un_alrdy' => 'Username already taken ...',
                'em_match' => 'Your E-mails do not match!',
                );


//Registration form
$fn    = strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
$ln    = strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']); 
$un    = strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
$dob   = date(@$_POST['dob']);
$loc   = strip_tags(@$_POST['location']);
$em    = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$em2   = strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);
$pswd  = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);
$d     = date("Y-m-d"); //Year - Month -  Day

if ($reg) {
    if ($em == $em2) {
//Check the username already exists
    $u_check = mysql_query(" SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un' ");
//Count the amount of rows where username = $un
    $check = mysql_num_rows($u_check);
//Check whether the email is already registered to DB       
    $e_check = mysql_query ("SELECT email FROM users Where email='$em'");
//Count the number of rows returned
    $email_check = mysql_num_rows ($e_check);       
        if ($check == 0) {
            if ($email_check == 0) {
//Check all of the fields have been filled in
            if ($fn && $ln && $un && $dob && $loc && $em && $em2 && $pswd && $pswd2) {
//Check the passwords match
                if ($pswd == $pswd2) {
//Check the maximum length of username/first name/last name does not exceed 25 characters
                    if (strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {
                    echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$result['un_limit']));
                    }
                else
                {
//Check the maximum length of the password does not exeed 25 characters and is not less than 8 characters
                    if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<8) {
                    echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$result['pw_length']));
                    }
                    else
                    {
//Encrypt password and password 2 using md5 before sending to DB
                    $pswd = md5($pswd);
                    $pswd2 = md5($pswd2);
                    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$dob','$loc','$em','$pswd','$d','0','','','','','','no')");
                    die("<h2>Account successfully created</h2>Login to your World of Videos account ..."); 
                    }   
                }   
                }
            else {
            echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$result['pw_match']));    
            }
            }
        else
        {
        echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$result['all_fields'])); 
        }
        }
        else
        {
        echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$result['em_alrdy']));
        }
        }
    else
    {
    echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$result['un_alrdy']));    
    }   
    }
else {
echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$result['em_match']));
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: what is your problem now with this code?

Comment: I want to display the echo messages which are generated when user fills the registration form wrong by my php script to my html page using jquery, but it is not working

Comment: You have to use `<div id= "test"> </div>` instead of `<div class = "test"> </div>`

Comment: use `e.preventDefault()` in your `click` event

Comment: put `alert(1)` after `function(signup_data)` have you get `alert`?

Comment: i tried event.preventDefault() it didn't work.

Comment: i tried alert(1), but it is not giving any alert and directing to php page.

Comment: you have to use `$("#reg").click( function(event) {` and the do `event.preventDefault()` after that.

Comment: i changed to event, no change yet

Comment: remove `$("#register-form").submit( function() {
    return false;
});` from `click`  event

Comment: why have you write `submit` event inside `click` event.

Comment: I removed them completely, still didn't work

Comment: i have written it to return false as the form is submitted

Comment: If you want to use `submit` then don't mix it with `click` event. Here only Click is ok.

Comment: $("#register-form").submit( function() {
        return false;
    });   ====>  I removed this part of code and tried, yet it is directing to php page only

Comment: i used die display a message if the form is submitted correctly to the database

Comment: Still redirect whole page?

Comment: yes, its still redirecting the whole page to php page only

Comment: You have to use `$.post( postdata
       function(signup_data) {
       },"json");`

Comment: can you please link me up with some example, Im fairly new to ajax, just trying to learn it these days

Comment: This will help you http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: i went through the page yesterday itself, and i came up with a new js and changed my php, but still its redirecting me to .php page itself, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery is not able to match, because your div has a class of "test", but your jQuery selector is for "id" since you are using $("#test")

Try either changing:
    `<div class="test">`
into 
    `<div id="test">`
in your html, or change the selector:
    `$("#test")`
into
    `$(".test")`

Comment: i changed it to id and tried, but it still is directing me to my php page and echoing the text

Comment: Then you might have to catch and prevent the default behavior of click on the form. Try `e.preventDefault()` in your click event.
Check this other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092580/stop-form-from-submitting-using-jquery

Comment: Please try to `echo` at server side. `$.post` reaches to php code?

Comment: it is echoing perfectly on my php page, but i want that to get directed to my html page,

Answer (score 0):

When I put this code on my system it didn't work, so I have improved the Jquery so it listens for the form to be submitted before doing it. Bare in mine I am using the latest version of jquery(2.1.4).

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

New HTML:

```
<form id="register-form">
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="firstname" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Firts name" value="">             
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" value="">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="text" name="dob" id="username" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="D-O-B">
    <input type="text" name="location" id="location" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Location">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="text" name="email2" id="email2" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Email">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-Enter Password">

    <input type="submit" name="reg" id="reg" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now" style="background: #1AB188; border: 0px; border-radius: 3px;">
</form>
```

New Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#register-form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent page change

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // Request type
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost/Exercises/media/index.php",
        data: $("#register-form").serialize(), // Get form data and organise it
        success: function(data) {
            $('#response').html(data.msg);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            $('#response').html("Error sending form data");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Please Note:

The new javascript should go after the form and from looking at your PHP code you are storing the passwords in an insecure way, please [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q) as hashing passwords with md5 is massively insecure. Also you are still using mysql instead of the new mysqli functions in your php, which shouldn't really be used anymore as it has security issues.

Comment: Thank you, the video is helpful. Coming to the JS part it is showing me the error message which is given in JS i.e"error sending from data", but what i need is to print the echo statements given in my php script in the "#test" div of my html when a user does not fill the form as per php conditions designed, i.e for example username does not exist etc,.

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean, I have a feeling it is to do with you having the link as "http://", why don't you try removing the "http://localhost" and do the actual path to the php script such as "/media/index.php"

Comment: my php and html are not in the same folders

Comment: So long as they are both on the same server you can link them. So if one was "localhost/media/index.php" then the other one in directory "localhost/html/index.html" would link like "../media/index.php" there is no need to type "localhost/media/index.php" as that can cause problems for other users/browsers

Comment: Yes, they are in the same folders how you expected. I have a question, in the near feature i want to bundle the html part as a .apk file using phone gap, as phone gap don't allow php, if i upload only the html files to phonegap build , is it going to work the same way ?

Comment: Well if you were to use phonegap(I have experience with it) then you would have the HTML make AJAX calls to the server which would have the PHP, the reason they don't allow PHP is because PHP is a server-side language and HTML is client side and so having PHP on the users device would be _pretty much_ useless.

Comment: i know, that is reason im trying to rebuild everything in html and ajax now, and that is the reason i want my php echo messages to be directed to my html page

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, good luck, I'd recommend reading the documentation it's really useful (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)