# click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i dont understand why the click function is not being called?Is there any mistake in jquery?

```
<div id="chatbox">

</div>

        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //If user submits the form
    $("#submitmsg").click(function(){

        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();

        jQuery.ajax({method:'post',url:'{{=URL('post')}}',
                     data:{'text':clientmsg,'touser'=touser},

                    success:function(data){
            $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
            return false;
        }})};

</script>
```

Comment: Just `type="button"`

Comment: man why you use form tag? jsut remove form tag and everything will work fine

Comment: @uzaif
my function is not working(not being called) if I do so

Comment: any console error?

Comment: @uzaif        ajax isn't running no network request on calling the ajax

Comment: try simple alert in click function

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
})
```

Check that for details: [Stop form from submitting , Using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092580/stop-form-from-submitting-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your button type to button so that the form is not submitted directly when clicked.
Then you need to stop the default function of the form by using event.preventDefault() method of jquery.I am only trying to resolve the problem of page refresh here.

```
      <form name="message" id="myForm" action="">
         <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
         <input name="submitmsg" type="button"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
     </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">

//If user submits the form
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();



    jQuery.ajax({method:'post',url:'{{=URL('post')}}',
                 data:$('#myForm').serialize(),//its the jquery method to serialize form data directly.
       success:function(data){
        $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");

    }})};
```