# HTML Text Input: Avoid submit when enter is pressed

Tags: html, textbox

I have an HTML input which is a textfield.
When I am pressing the enter, this will call the submit, which is normal.

Now, I would like to do something else when Enter is clicked on that textBox.

I am trying something like that:

```
<input type="text" 
       id="first_page"  
       onPaste="" 
       onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) alert('enter')" />
```

The alert works well but the submit is still done. My page is reloading after that.

Could you help me please.

Comment: you dont neeed 'onPaste' parameter

Answer (score 26, accepted):

write `return false;` and check it

Comment: This is now marked as deprecated. Should now be event.preventDefault() and/or event.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 27):

Using jQuery:

```
<script>
  $('#first_page').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '13') {
      e.preventDefault();
      //your code here
    }
  });​
</script>
```

using javascript

```
<input type="text" id="first_page" onPaste="" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { alert('enter');return false;}" />
```

Comment: could shorthand it with... 
onkeydown="event.keyCode == 13 && event.preventDefault()"

Answer (score 7):

Other option would be using onkeypress

```
<input type="text" id="first_page"  onPaste="" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {alert('enter'); return false;}" />
```

Comment: in the if statement you need {}'s or else you are always going to return false for any key pressed.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below script :

```
<script>
  function checkEnter(event)
  {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) 
    {
      alert('enter')
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

And the Html:

```
<input type="text" id="first_page" onPaste="" onkeydown="return checkEnter(event);" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be returning `false` in the `keydown` event handler function in order to prevent further processing of the event.

Also, you might find the following question useful: [Prevent Users from submitting form by hitting enter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/895171/851811).

Answer (score 1):

write the following code after `alert('enter')`

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, it worked in mine.

Replace on the keydown:

```
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) event.preventDefault();"
```

Comment: Thanks @Michelle i still new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(function () {$('#form').validationEngine(); });
```

It will work in my mvc problem

Answer (score -3):

using jquery you can avoid all submiting or some element

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This will prevent the form from being submitted at all, which I doubt is the intent of the OP.