# Submitting form in Browser and multithreading in javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, forms, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent Users from submitting form by hitting enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter)

I wrote some simple code ([you can also test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/mj8Kv/5/) )

```
<form >
       <input id="id2" type='text' />
</form>
$("#id2").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('nope!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

If I click enter I should see an alert with "nope!" and then nothing. But, after I click "ok" on the alert window, the form is submitting despite the function returning false.

What is it? Something strange multithreading in javascript? Bug? Or...

​

Answer (score 2):

Use the `keypress` event rather than the `keydown` event:

```
$("#id2").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('nope!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mj8Kv/10/)