# What event is triggered when the pageload (e.g. during form submit) is cancelled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

A form is submitted (files attached), the submit button gets disabled, then the user realizes some mistake and suddenly cancels the page. He is stuck on the page without the ability of submitting his data.

Is there an event to listen, which generated when the user cancels the form submit? This should lead a re-enabled submit button. The `keyup` event (for the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key) is not enough, since the user can click on the browser's cancel button.

Comment: There is no such event.

Comment: The browser's cancel button? Where is that button? You'll have to provide a definition for "cancel the page".

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It's right there where the reload button is, for most browsers. You probably didn't recognize since it likes to hide if it's not needed. ;)

Comment: @Derija93 That's the "stop loading" button (usually a red X).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Don't you think that's exactly what he means? Oh, and chrome has a black X.

Comment: I think that this link might be what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter

Comment: @ŠimeVidas The button with a big X on it, that stops loading the page. I need something like "onloadcancelled" or "onreadyagain"...

Comment: @user123_456 Thanks, I'm aware of this. The user can freely submit the form, but while the files are uploading he might spot a mistake, and want to correct it, before the form is completely sent.

Comment: Although adeneo says there is no event, perhaps you could look into the onabort event. http://help.dottoro.com/ljxraqdn.php for more info.