# I do not want to set default input type submit in form [.net mvc]

Tags: asp.net-mvc

input name 'btnSaveScore' is clicked When keypress ENTER in TextBox.

I do not want to call 'btnSaveScore' when keypress ENTER in TextBox.

I guess that 'btnSaveScore' is a default button.

Can I set default button = false ?

```
//Code

 @using (Html.BeginForm("ScoreStudent", "Score", FormMethod.Post))
{
  ...
  ...
  ...
 <input name ="btnSaveScore" id="btnSaveScore" value="submit score" type="submit" /> 
}
//End Code
```

Help me please, Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent Users from submitting form by hitting enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an MVC problem - this is a HTML issue. If your button isn't supposed to `submit` the form then don't use `type="submit"` use `type="button"` instead.

Alternatively you can solve it using JS

```
$("#form").keypress(function(e){
    return e.which != 13;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `onkeydown` attribute in your textbox in following way:

```
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;"
```

Your textbox should be like this:

```
<input type="text" id="textboxId" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input name ="btnSaveScore" id="btnSaveScore" value="submit score" type="submit" />
```

to

```
 <input name ="btnSaveScore" id="btnSaveScore" value="submit score" type="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. 
Code below is work for me

```
$('#textboxname').live("keypress", function (e) 
{ 
  if (e.keyCode == 13) 
  { 
       // do something 

       e.preventDefault(); 
       return false; 
  } 
});
```

and

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ScoreStudent", "Score", FormMethod.Post)) 
{ 
 ... 
 ... 
 <input name ="btnSaveScore" id="btnSaveScore" value="submit score" type="submit" /> 
}
```