# Disable enter key from submitting form and can be used in textarea to enter new line

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code. I tried this in firefox as well as chrome but it us not working

Html:

```
  <form id="leform">
    <div>
        Name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
        <textarea type="text" name="lastname"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {

        if (e.which == 13 && e.target.tagName != "TEXTAREA") {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: please provide the html too

Comment: Please use `jquery`. similar question and answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter

Comment: Text area by default will not submit the form. Are you talking about textbox?

Comment: e.target.tagName != "TEXTAREA" should this be e.target.tagName == "TEXTAREA"

Comment: It works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/F26Lh/

Comment: See in console, Are you sure you have included jquery properly?