# Search form: submit when a name is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my search box, when a user presses three letters, a list of potential hits is shown.

But when a user selects a name from this list, he still has to press enter. How can I avoid this When he selects his name, his name should be automatically be submitted.

UPDATE: And is it possible to only submit when a user selects a name from the list, and not when he presses enter?

This is the HTML code:

```
    <form action="10_miles.php" method="post">
        <p><label>Please enter your LAST name and find your name in the list: </label><br><br>
        <input type='text' name='full_name' value='' class='auto'></p>
    </form>
```

I am making use of this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            $(".auto").autocomplete({
                source: "search_develop.php",
                minLength: 3
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: jQuery? Or pure JavaScript?

Comment: and where is the list?

Comment: You mean an autocomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this like;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            $(".auto").autocomplete({
                source: "search_develop.php",
                minLength: 3, 
                change: function (event, ui) { 
                     $('form').submit(); 
                },
                close: function (event, ui) { 
                     $('form').submit(); 
                }
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it that the form is only submitted if a name is selected, not when the user pressed enter?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can handle which key is pressed. Then check it is enter or not. If it is enter you call events' preventDefault function. You can find detail in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selector').click(function(){   
       $('form').submit(); 
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, now if I even click in the search box he submits. He can only submit if a a name is clicked

Comment: You should replace your name selector with name. your autocompelte list should have a tag or selector.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've already accepted an answer, I thought it would be nice to put a pure JavaScript related answer.

```
setInterval(function(){
    if (document.getElementById("name").value.toLowerCase() == "marzonie") {
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML='Does equal.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML='Doesn\'t equal.';
    }
}, 100);

document.getElementById("submit_form").onsubmit=function( event ){ event.preventDefault(); }
```

It loops every 100ms and validates input's value if it is equal to "marzonie" or not, and it changes status' `innerHTML` accordingly.

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/N8ad3/2/)