# Avoid Enter Key Form Submit in Pop Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I am using a `Bootstrap Pop up`. This Pop up gets opened from `Main Form`.

In this Pop up, I have `TextBox` & a `Button`.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchEmployee()" />
```

When I hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key when `Pop up` is open, the `Main Form` gets `submitted`. The Main Form has a submit button.

How can I avoid form `submit` in pop up on <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press?

And on the contrary enable `ENTER` key submit, when `pop up` is closed.

Comment: I need to prevent users from submitting form by hitting enter only when pop up is opened.

Comment: Then you can bind the little code to prevent the submit just for the form inside a modal, with a selector such as ```$('.modal form')```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#formid').on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (code  == 13) {               
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Disabling the default behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter) of a form submission can be achieved by using `event.preventDefault();` by catching the event of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> button being clicked.

There are other ways to simply disable all submits depending on how specific you want to be, best way is to identify a specific id:

```
document.getElementById("submitButtonId").disabled = true;
```

But you can also specify which submit buttons are to be disabled if they're identifed with a class or if you simply wish to disable all submits of all kinds by using `getElementByClass` or  `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: This pop up is used in many places, so `id` is different every time.

Comment: @Anup You can use `getElementByClass` if the submit buttons have a provided class. You can use `getElementsByTagName` if it's suppose to match all elements of some specific type, i.e. `submit`.