# How to prevent enter key from submitting a form but still allow enter to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using XOXCO Tags-Input.

Here is a demo http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/example.html

So in order to complete a tag i have to hit enter but when i hit enter it submits my form.

I can disable enter for the whole form with this code but then i can't complete a tag.

```
$("#form").keypress(function(e) {
    //Enter key
    if (e.which == 13) {
    return false;
    }
});
```

So i still need enter to work but i also need it to not submit the form and i'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved it in case anyone else runs into this problem here is what i did.

```
$('form input').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input");
            if (inputs[inputs.index(this) + 1] != null) {                    
                inputs[inputs.index(this) + 1].focus();
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default behavior of the enter press, which is to submit the form. For example...

```
$('#form').keypress(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
    // do stuff with the keypress
    $('#form').submit(); // now, submit the form
});
```

Comment: Do you have a better explanation of how i would do this.

Comment: Submit the form later? You should be able to, wherever in your function that you want to, call $('#form').submit() to submit the form manually. If needed, I can update my answer with those details.

Comment: If you could update your answer that might help.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is:

```
$('form').on('keypress keydown keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        //alert(e.which); 
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhujkub7/

Comment: You're right!  Updated with working example.  Cred goes to this answer by  Dave Paroulek http://stackoverflow.com/a/9891024/1477388