# PHP and Ajax posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using jQuery form plugin to send ajax requests. Which you can find on below url

```
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/
```

This is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#SubmitForm').on('submit', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#submitButton').attr('disabled', ''); 

        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '#output',
        success:  afterSuccess //call function after success
        });
    });
});

function afterSuccess()
{   

    $('#submitButton').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button

}
```

This code is displaying out put on the div id output and each time i submitted code will remove the old out put and display the new one. What i want to do is, keep the old out and display the new out put on top of the old output. Can someone tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could do, is alter your `afterSuccess` method a little bit. What I did was:

```
function afterSuccess(text)
{  
    $('#output').prepend(text)
    $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

The whole fiddle is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkr10ro6/50/)

The whole code of javascript:

```
function afterSuccess(text)
{  
    $('#output').prepend(text)
    $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', false);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#submitButton').click(function(e)
    {
        $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#SubmitForm').ajaxSubmit({
            data: {
                html: "<p>Text echoed back to request</p>",
                delay: 1
            },
            success:  afterSuccess,
            url: '/echo/html/'
        });
    });
});
```

and of course assuming following html structure

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.min.js"></script> 

<body>
    <form id="SubmitForm" method="POST">
        <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="submit"/>
    </form>     
    <div id="output">
        test
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just like to ask you one thing. How to stop the form from reloading the page when enter? i tried preventDefault() didn't seems to work out

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter

Comment: i dont wont to stop the key enter. I just dont want it to refresh the page when pressing enter key