# jQuery: disable 'enter' only when a field has focus

Tags: jquery, onfocus, lost-focus

When you press `enter` on the keyboard, a form is sent automatically.
I wish this were not the case only if a specific field (`#myText`) has focus when you press `enter`.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/895231/1480263), I have this code now:

```
$('#myText').on('focusin', function() {
    console.log('focusin');

    $(window).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            console.log('enter!');
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work well, because when the field loses the focus, pressing `enter` nothing happens.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't binding your keydown event to the specific input.  Change this line:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
```

to this:

```
$(this).off('keydown').keydown(function(event){
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cx95LxLx/2/)

Comment: Everytime input#myText gets focus a new event handler will get created. Change your code to: `$(this).off('keydown').keydown(function(event){`