# Call same method on different entering

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to realize a autocomplete input. It works fine, as far as u don't press enter, then the method "get" posts a empty string to my servlet (in Background). How I must modify the code, that the same GET-Request will also be generated when pressing enter. You can test out "the problem" on http://ajax.scienceandit.net .

```
  <form name="autofillform" method="GET" action="autocomplete.php">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Composer Name:</strong></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" size="40"
                               id="complete-field"
                               onkeyup="doCompletion();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="auto-row" colspan="2">
                        <table class="popupBox" style="display: none"></table>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var req;
var isIE;
var completeField;
var completeTable;
var autoRow;

function init() {
    completeField = document.getElementById("complete-field");
    completeTable = document.createElement("table");
    completeTable.setAttribute("class", "popupBox");
    completeTable.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
    autoRow = document.getElementById("auto-row");
    autoRow.appendChild(completeTable);
    completeTable.style.top = getElementY(autoRow) + "px";
}

function doCompletion() {
        var url = "autocomplete.php?action=complete&id=" + escape(completeField.value);
        req = initRequest();
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.onreadystatechange = callback;
        req.send(null);
}

function initRequest() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1) {
            isIE = true;
        }
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        isIE = true;
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}

function callback() {
    clearTable();

    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            parseMessages(req.responseXML);
        }
    }
}

function appendComposer(firstName,lastName,composerId) {

    var row;
    var cell;
    var linkElement;

    if (isIE) {
        completeTable.style.display = 'block';
        row = completeTable.insertRow(completeTable.rows.length);
        cell = row.insertCell(0);
    } else {
        completeTable.style.display = 'table';
        row = document.createElement("tr");
        cell = document.createElement("td");
        row.appendChild(cell);
        completeTable.appendChild(row);
    }

    cell.className = "popupCell";

    linkElement = document.createElement("a");
    linkElement.className = "popupItem";
    linkElement.setAttribute("href", "autocomplete.php?action=lookup&id=" + composerId);
    linkElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstName + " " + lastName));
    cell.appendChild(linkElement);
}

function clearTable() {
    if (completeTable.getElementsByTagName("tr").length > 0) {
        completeTable.style.display = 'none';
        for (loop = completeTable.childNodes.length -1; loop >= 0 ; loop--) {
            completeTable.removeChild(completeTable.childNodes[loop]);
        }
    }
}

function getElementY(element){

    var targetTop = 0;

    if (element.offsetParent) {
        while (element.offsetParent) {
            targetTop += element.offsetTop;
            element = element.offsetParent;
        }
    } else if (element.y) {
        targetTop += element.y;
    }
    return targetTop;
}

function parseMessages(responseXML) {

    // no matches returned
    if (responseXML == null) {
        return false;
    } else {

        var composers = responseXML.getElementsByTagName("composers")[0];

        if (composers.childNodes.length > 0) {
            completeTable.setAttribute("bordercolor", "black");
            completeTable.setAttribute("border", "1");

            for (loop = 0; loop < composers.childNodes.length; loop++) {
                var composer = composers.childNodes[loop];
                var firstName = composer.getElementsByTagName("firstName")[0];
                var lastName = composer.getElementsByTagName("lastName")[0];
                var composerId = composer.getElementsByTagName("id")[0];
                appendComposer(firstName.childNodes[0].nodeValue,
                    lastName.childNodes[0].nodeValue,
                    composerId.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter

Comment: when you press enter, how do you know which composer in the autocomplete is selected?