# addNewRow with Enter Key via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code :

```
$(document).on('keypress', ".addNewRow", function(e){
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 9 ) addNewRow();
});
```

Upon pressing "Tab" this code executes addNewRow (which adds table data).  This works perfect.  I want to alter this to make it work with "Enter", so I modified as follows :

```
$(document).on('keypress', ".addNewRow", function(e){
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 9,13 ) addNewRow();
});
```

For some odd reason, this does not work as expected.  Is there a different way of doing this that I am missing? *Banging head on wall

Edit : Also have tried this :

```
$(document).on('keypress', ".addNewRow", function(e){
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 9||13 ) addNewRow();
});
```

Form Code(To prevent submit on enter) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tabE(obj, e) {
  var e = (typeof event != 'undefined') ? window.event : e; // IE : Moz

  var self = $(obj),
    form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'),
    focusable, next;

  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
    next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(obj) + 1);
    if (!next.length) {
      next = focusable.first();
    }
    next.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
<!-- Prevent Enter from Submitting Form -->
<script>
                    $(document).on("keydown", "input", function(e) {
                    if (e.which==13) e.preventDefault();
                    });
                    </script>
    <!-- Begin page content -->
```

Comment: Try "keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/8bzn43r6/ Please see the example in the link

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type = "text" id="username"/></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;

  function addNewRow(){
    console.log("Added ROW" + count++);
    $("<tr><td><input type='text' id='username'/><td/><tr/>").appendTo("tbody");
  }

    $('tbody').on('keydown','#username',function(e){
     if(e.keyCode == 9 || e.keyCode == 13) addNewRow();
  });

});
```

Working like a charm

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know what I did wrong, but I rewrote what I had with yours and it fixed...

Comment: btw, would you know how to skip a checkbox on focus of the new row?

Comment: My addRow function creates an html +=<input type=checkbox> on the first form field of the next row, in addition to more inputs.  I would like to skip the first input after implementing the addRow function.

Answer (score 3):

Proper `or` statement:

```
if (keyCode == 9 || keyCode  == 13)
```

Comment: Thanks for the proper syntax, for some reason, it is still not working...?  The tab key still works a charm though

Comment: @Steven When you say "it's not working", in what way?  Random guess, but are your input elements within a `<form>`?  Hitting enter may be submitting the form?

Comment: @Steven [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter).

Comment: I have both that code, and code to convert enter to tab

Answer (score -3):

do you want your if as an OR?

```
if(keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13 )
```

or as an AND?

```
if(keyCode == 9 && keyCode == 13 )
```

Comment: That AND condition will always yield a false.