# Enter key not to submit - how to return false

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want Enter Key not to submit a form. I did this first.

```js
  $("#send_c").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
```

But the button and Enter key work the same. Nothing happens or submitted even by the Enter key. My second try is this.

```html
<%=form_for [@article, @article.comments.build], remote: true, :onsubmit=>"return false;" do |f| %>
  <%=f.text_field :body, id: "c_i"%>
  <%=f.button :submit, id: "send_c"%>
<%end%>
```

This did not work. The form is submitted both by Enter key and submit button.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `e.which == 13` with `e.keyCode == 13`.

Comment: I did this, but this did not work ... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh... my mistake was $("#send_c") part. It should be $("form"). Solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is the selector

```
$("#send_c").keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
```

`$("#send_c")` is a selector of submit button, instead you may have to give the selector as `$(window)`
You can use the below script to accomplish the task

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

For reference please see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:

```
function x13(x) { if(x.keyCode==13) return false; }
```

In html:

```
<input onkeypress="return x13(event)">
```