# How to submit a form with button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to submit values of input forms by click a button only. Generally pressing enter also submit the from, bt I need to prevent that. I only need to submit all input data if button is clicked.

So, I use `window.location='insert_expences.php'`, but in insert_expences.php I can't get the values of input field. I use `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_POST);die;`

I want to get all input values only when button is clicked.

**Plz help Thanks**

Comment: Use `document.getElementById('FORM_ID').submit()` on button click...and `document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){ if(e.keyCode == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
    } })`

Comment: should I remove `window.location`

Comment: @RayonDabre—why is the first required? The default behaviour of a submit button is to submit the form, it doesn't need a listener to do that.

Comment: @Mr.Shrestha, You should remove `window.location...`

Comment: @RobG, I assumed OP is dealing with `type = "button"`

Comment: There are plenty of answers to this by doing a quick search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter

Comment: I add form = 'gothere.php'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Complete working code** to prevent form submission on Enter/Return Key. It will submit the form when user click on the Submit button.

1.php file

```
<?php
/* Add your php code here if needed */
?>
 <!-- form starts -->
<form action="2.php" method="post" id="regForm">
 <input name="a" type="text" />
 <input name="b" type="text" />
 <input name="sub" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<!-- form ends-->

 <!-- Insert the code below before </body> Tag -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
   $('#regForm').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
   var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
     if (keyCode === 13) {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
     }
  });
 </script>
```

2.php file

```
 <?php
//Show the form data that was sent here
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_POST);
die;
?>
```

To learn more about PHP, please see the following links

[PHP with HTML](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/php_with_html.htm) - [PHP 5 Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) - [learn php](http://www.learn-php.org/)

Comment: `<script>
$('#regForm').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
 var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (keyCode === 13) { 
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
   }
 });
 </script>
<form action="insert_expences.php" id="regForm">  </form>` inside form there are many input text and insert button having `type='button'`

Comment: `<script>
 $('#regForm').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
 var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (keyCode === 13) { 
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
   }
 });
</script>
<form action="2.php" method="get" id="regForm">

<input name="a" type="text" />
<input name="b" type="text" />
<input name="sub" type="button" value="Submit" />

</form>`

Comment: Here is  working example [form submission with button only](https://jsfiddle.net/qammar/y3tcek4j/11/)

Comment: @Mr. Shrestha, answer if updated. if this solve the problem? If yes, accept the answer by clicking on green tick mark with the answer.

Comment: u are using `type='submit'`, in fiddle pressing enter key doesn't works..... it is good and i want like that but when i tried in real i.e in 1.php and 2.php pressing enter key also works like clicking submit. In short it doesn't works in real page

Comment: I thnk u didn't understand my question.

Comment: Just try urself. Copy your code in 1.php and display var_dump($_GET) in 2.php, this will submit form while pressing enter key.

Comment: If there are other JavaScript errors/bugs in your code, It will NOT work. Test it in a separate HTML/PHP file. thx

Comment: no there are no other codes. I create 1.php and 2.php to check ur code only. there are not a single word then ur code

Comment: u may check by ur self and press enter that will submit for

Comment: Answer updated with working php code. I guess, you know, how to execute php scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `submit` and use button:

`<input type="button" value="" id="button">`

And add listener to button:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```