# How to change my js function from on click of enter to when i click submit button

Tags: javascript

I have a js script that I am extending to meet my needs as I'm still pretty new to JavaScript and have tried a few things but cant seem to get them to work.Here is part of JavaScript script if more is needed I can put more of it up.What I would like to do is have it work exactly the same way but instead of hitting the enter key i want to have the user click submit (or a button that looks like submit would work too) with their mouse.

```
(function () {

'use strict';

var ENTER_KEY = 13
var auditor = document.getElementById('auditor');
var date = document.getElementById('date');
var location = document.getElementById('location');
var workers = document.getElementById('workers');
var contact = document.getElementById('contact');
```

Where ENTER_KEY gets used (for second time)

```
  function newTodoKeyPressHandler( event ) {
if (event.keyCode === ENTER_KEY) {
   addTodo(auditor.value,date.value,location.value,workers.value,contact.value,company.value,exposureLocation.value,workersExposed.value,exposures.value,interventions.value,interventionComments.value,additionalComments.value,programManagement.value);
  auditor.value = '';
  date.value= '';
  location.value = '';
  workers.value = '';
  contact.value = '';
  company.value = '';
  exposureLocation.value = '';
  workersExposed.value = '';
  exposures.value = '';
  interventions.value = '';
  interventionComments.value = '';
  additionalComments.value = '';
  programManagement.value = '';

 }
}
```

If anyone could help to accomplish this I would greatly appreciate it. I already know ill have to change event.keyCode to something else but the things I tried were to no avail. Thanks

Comment: try referring this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, your newTodoKeyPressHandler is being invoked on press of a keyboard button.
Basically, you need to define an event handler for mouse click and then add a listener for the same as follows:

```
 document.getElementById('button').addEventListener(
    'click',
    mouseClickHandler,
    false
 );
```

// mouseClickHandler Function

```
 function mouseClickHandler(event){
     ... (handler code, same as in the keypress handler)

 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think i pretty much get it, although what does false do?

Comment: Do check out detailed documentation of addEventListener here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener . Basically, the third parameter is an options array, and you can check out the documentation for all possible options.

Answer (score 1):

there a few ways of doing this you can try this first

```
<button onclick=" newTodoKeyPressHandler()">Click me</button>
```

you create the button with a onclick attribute and set the function to do that but you may need to add return false to prevent default action in the form from posting and reloading the page.