# Unwanted form submit using jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code :

```
$('#myinput').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13)
        alert('test, do not submit my form plesae !');
});
```

Problem is, 'myinput' is inside a form. When i press ENTER on this input, i want to only show the alert message, but my form is being submitted. How to avoid it ?

I tried this :

```
$('#myinput').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13)
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('test, do not submit my form plesae !');
        return false;
});
```

But no lucky, the form is still being submitted.

Thanks !

Comment: please share the html

Comment: This solved for me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter