# HTML Form submit on enter press

Tags: html, forms

I saw a strange behaviour while developing HTML form. This one I didn't notice previously. So I am curious.

Suppose following is form element.

```
<form>
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="text" name="c">
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit">
</form>
```

When input `name='a'` is focused and I press enter, the form is getting submitted by default.

I always thought form get's submitted when enter is pressed in last input element, i.e., in this case `name='c'`.

Now, how to make form get submitted only when enter is pressed on last input element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I always thought form get's submitted when enter is pressed in last input element

No.

A form will be submitted when Enter is pressed on *any* input.

---

> Now, how to make form get submitted only when enter is pressed on last input element?

This is not normal behaviour. It goes against user expectations. I recommend against doing this.

- Bind a keypress event handler to each input except the last one
- Check if the key is Enter
- Call `preventDefault()` on the event object if it is