# Deny submit when I click "enter" on specific form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is might be a little tricky.

I have a form with 10 text boxes(consider its name1, name2 .. name10)

what I want is when I focus on `name1` text box and I hit "enter", the form should not submitted. instead  I want to call a function.

but when I hit "enter" while focusing other form elements rather than `name1`, the form should get submitted.

Please suggest me if you think there are any other idea to do this.

**NOTE: I cant move the element outside of the form.**

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: add a separate event handler to `name1`. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use keypress event for the first input element and prevent the form from submitting by using `event.preventDefault();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#name1").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      calculate() // call your function here
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  
  $( 'form' ).on( 'submit' , () => { // arrow function
    console.log("submited"); // form
} );
  function calculate() {
    console.log("prevent submitting");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="name1" type="text" />  
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: why do you have `event.preventDefault();` and `return false;` together? do they not serve the same purpose? Also any specific reason for your 1st event handler is a normal function and your second event handler is an arrow function??

Comment: @SudiptoRoy here it is no use. If you would like to skip all code after the  `event.preventDefault();`  in the keydown method then you must use the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.code === 'Enter' && $(e.target).is('textarea')) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bro. looking the above answer is exactly I wanted. thanks for help me to learn this kind of approach. :)