# event.stopPropagation() not working on forms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I have a simple angular form, for example:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div>
      <input type="text" (keydown.enter)="onEnterPerssed($event)" [formControl]="myList" formControlName="myList">
    </div>
   <br>

    <p *ngIf="sendData" class="mt-1">Data send successfully</p>

    <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(form)" class="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-2" style="width: 100px;" [disabled]="form.invalid">
    Submit
    </button>
  </form>
```

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  sendData: boolean = false;

  form: FormGroup;
  isDisabled: boolean = true;
  myList: FormControl = new FormControl('sdfsdf', [Validators.required  ]);

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      myList: this.myList
    });
  }

  onSubmit(form): void {
    this.sendData = true;
    console.log('data send successfully');
  }

  onEnterPerssed(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('asdasfasfsfafasfasf');
  }
}
```

Is there any solutions on how to prevent submitting form while we click Enter on the input field, without changing button type (submit => button)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter)

Comment: In the code example you provided, the Enter key disabled in the whole document. I try to understand why event.stopPropagation() doesn't work in the input filed.

Comment: what do you mean `the Enter key disabled in the whole document`? you can actually use the enter key to fill a textarea, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change submit event on `form` tag, and remove click event from submit button.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
```

```js
onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // logic goes here
}
```

`ngSubmit` ensures that the form doesn’t submit when the handler code throws (which is the default behaviour of submit) and causes an actual http post request.

Comment: Look no further!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in the template:**

Use `(keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()` inside the `form` tag

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
    <div>
      <input type="text" (keydown.enter)="onEnterPerssed($event)" [formControl]="myList" formControlName="myList">
    </div>
   <br>

    <p *ngIf="sendData" class="mt-1">Data send successfully</p>

    <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(form)" class="btn btn-block btn-primary mt-2" style="width: 100px;" [disabled]="form.invalid">
    Submit
    </button>
  </form>
```