# How do I prevent the page from resetting when submitting form

Tags: javascript, html

When clicking the enter button on the keyboard I want the data to show but not to reset. But if I input new data and click enter I want it to run still without clicking a reset button.

```js
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "$" + (x * '.97').toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
     <input id="myText" placeholder="$149,995.00" style="width:50%;" type="number"> 
            <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Convert</button>
 </form>
        <h1 id="demo"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to handle the form's `submit` event, not the button click. [More on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted).

Comment: Would you be able to write it out in code for me? New to coding. @isherwood

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter

Comment: remove the `<form>` element so you just have the input and button.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preventDefault` function from event not to refresh the page.
By default, whenever a `form` is submitted, the page is refreshed.
Moreover, by default, any `input` inside a `form` tag submits the form with an enter key pressed.

The reason you were not being refreshed with the button is that the form was not being submitted with the button click. But it was with an enter key press event in the input.

Try this

```
<form>
    <input placeholder="$149,995.00" style="width:50%;" type="number" id="input">
    <input type="submit" value="Convert">
</form>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

```
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { value } = input;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = toDollar(value);
}));

const toDollar = (value) => 
    "$" + (value * '.97').toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

Now, you add a listener to the `submit` event of the `form`, so you receive an `event` object where to call `preventDefault` and avoid the page refresh.