# Prevent users from triggering the onSubmit handler by pressing enter in a react form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I have a simple react form with an onSubmit handler. Inside the handler a post request is made.
It's like this

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('...', method post, body ... etc)
    setStatus(await response.text())
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my function is basically still triggered by the enter button so it makes a post request. I want this to only happen when someone actually clicks the button. I thought maybe I could do this by filtering on the event keyCode but I can't find it.

Comment: _“but I can't find it”_ - are you sure you actually _searched_ in the first place? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter

Comment: Ofcourse but none of the answers in there worked. Most are jquery based solutions.

Comment: So what, that changes very little about the _principle_.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `onKeyPress` props, e.g:

```
const handleKeyPress = (event)  = {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
},

return (
    <form onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}...
)
```

NOTE: The submit event is executed (when onSubmit is also executed) when you use onSubmit, So it is too late at that time to prevent the default action.

Comment: Thanks bro! This seems to work, I now have <form onSubmit={submitHandler} onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}>.

Comment: @Blackfrwhite Noice!, there is no problem if you use onSubmit next to onKeyPress.