# Html form some how auto submits on enter

Tags: html, node.js, forms, templates, onfocus

I have this html template in handlebars and like 52 input fields and i have this `focusnext()` function to focus on to the next input field regardless its required or not

**html code from template**

```
<form action="/newclient/{{accountName}}" onsubmit="return checkUSerCredentials();" method="POST">
<div class="row">
     <h1 class="col s6" style="margin-top:4%;">NEW CLIENT</h1>
    <div style="float: right; margin-top:4.5%;">
        <button type="submit" id="save" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large roundeed teal lighten-1">
            <i class="material-icons left">done_all</i>Create New Agreement
        </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> 
    <div class="input-field col s4" onkeydown="focusNext(event)">
    <input id="ledger_num" name="ledger_num"type="text" class="validate" required>
    <label for="ledger_num"><b>Ledger Number</b></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s4" onkeydown="focusNext(event)">
    <input id="file_num" name="file_num" type="text" class="validate" required>
    <label for="file_num"><b>File Number</b></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s4" onkeydown="focusNext(event)">
        <input id="agereement_date" placeholder="Example : 31/12/2021" name="agereement_date" type="text" class="validate" required pattern="^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$">
        <label for="agereement_date">Agereement Date</label>
    </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="Row">
    <div class="input-field Column" onkeydown="focusNext(event)">
    <input id="client_name" name="client_name" type="text" class="validate" required>
    <label for="client_name">Client Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field Column" onkeydown="focusNext(event)">
        <input id="client_gaurdian" name="client_gaurdian" type="text" class="validate" >
        <label for="client_gaurdian">Parent/Guardian</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field Column" onkeydown="focusNext(event)">
        <input id="guarantor_name" name="guarantor_name" type="text" class="validate" >
        <label for="guarantor_name">Guarantor Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field Column" onkeydown="focusNext(event)">
        <input id="guarantor_gaurdian" name="guarantor_gaurdian" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="guarantor_gaurdian">Parent/Guardian</label>
    </div>
.
.
.
.
.
.
</form>
```

and this is the function i use to focus on to the next input field

```
<script>
    const inputField_ID_array = ["ledger_num","file_num","agereement_date","client_name","client_gaurdian",
    "guarantor_name","guarantor_gaurdian".............]


    function focusNext (e) {
      try{
        for(var i = 0; i<textArray.length; i++) {

          if(e.keyCode === 13 && e.target.id === textArray[i]){  
            M.updateTextFields();
            document.querySelector(`#${textArray[i+1]}`).focus();
          }

        } 
      }catch(error){} 
    }
</script>
```

this is inside the same template file inside a script tag
**so the problem is when ever I prese enter instead of focusing on to the next input field i some how go to  the next `required` input field and if remove the `require` condition from all input fields it simply sends the post request ( I don't know what is going on)**

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior of HTML forms, you have to manually disable this feature via Javascript or by creating an hidden submit button to prevent this.

Please refere to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51507806/6419298)