# Pressing enter key on input field triggers button click function

Tags: javascript, html

```html
    <form onsubmit="myFunction()">
        Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
        <!--input type="submit" value="Submit"-->
        <button onclick="alert('button click')">click</button>
    </form>
```

press enter on input triggers button onclick, form is submitted. How to avoid button onclick trigger.

Comment: This is a standard feature on all browsers. Enter in a form = submit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter)

Comment: form onsubmit function will execute. but  how onclick on button inside the form. is getting executed. any hack to avoid this.

Comment: It submits by "clicking" the submit button related to the form.  If you change the button to `type='button'` it won't be clicked, but then won't submit so your button click then also needs to submit the form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you have a button in a form, it defaults to type "submit" which means the first button in a form will have its onclick event triggered by the ENTER key. To prevent this from happening, simply assign type="button" to the button, and enter key will no longer affect it.

Comment: is this actually part of the spec? or something that just happens to work in 2022

Comment: @mattrichards it was always like this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
    Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
    <!--input type="submit" value="Submit"-->
    <button onclick="alert('button click')" id="btn">click</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var input = document.getElementById("fname");
    input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("btn").click();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: keypress is deprecated [Element: keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event] use 'keydown' instead [](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event)