# disabling functionality of the enter key for a file upload

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling enter key for form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629805/disabling-enter-key-for-form)

How do I disable the enter key on a file upload input box.  I submit this form progmatically in javascript.  I don't want the user to submit it by pressing the enter key (this is what happens when the user presses the enter key).

The  programatic submit is with in an ajax call like this.

```
document.f1_1.submit();
```

It calls the .php file listed in the attribute of the form f1_1.

Thanks

Comment: is there no way to bring the .php reference into the javascrit itself?  I don't think so.  Ajax can not handle file uploads last I heard.

Comment: function bind_fu(event)
  {
  if(event.keyCode==13)
    {
 return false;
    }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From google and assuming no javascript library like Jquery:

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Disable-Form-Submit-on-Enter-Key-Press.aspx

Comment: link into the event stream...in the javascript ...o.k.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier than the other SO and google posts I've seen.  Works on IE 9 at a minimum.

Just bind this method to the input box:

```
function bind_fu(event)
  {
  if(event.keyCode==13)
    {
    return false;
    }
  }
```