# event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#changeResumeStatus").click(function () {
        $.get("{% url 'main:changeResumeStatus' %}", function (data) {
            if (data['message'] == 'hidden') {
                $("#resumeStatus").text("скрыто");
            } else {
                $("#resumeStatus").text("опубликовано");
            }
        }, "json");
    });
});
</script>
```

I receive the following error in my Google Chrome console:

> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

I am using jQuery v1.10.2 and `#changeResumeStatus` is a `<span>`.

What's wrong with my script?

Comment: I think that's not an error, but merely a warning - this one can be safely ignored.

Comment: This warning is following lastest chrome update, don't worry

Comment: You should look into escaping non-ascii strings.

Comment: @Gleno what for? my templates work completely fine in utf-8

Comment: @AlexParakhnevich There's no single compelling reason to do so, but a few minor ones that creep up from time to time. My reaction was instinctive rather than well thought out, to be honest. In projects I'm working on right now, there's a guideline to not use non-ascii chars in literals, which I instituted in the past, because some external tools (typescript compiler) choked on such input. It works well enough in most cases, but sometimes eats up a lot of developer time when things go wrong. Anyway, `.empty().append("text")` is better expressed as `.text("text")`.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

This is only a warning: your code still works, but probably won't work in the future as the method is deprecated. See the [relevant source of Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/frame/UseCounter.cpp&q=event.returnValue%20deprecated&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=673) and [corresponding patch](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/frame/UseCounter.cpp?revision=156916).

This has already been recognised and fixed in jQuery 1.11 (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905072429/http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14282) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150524010302/http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14320)).

Comment: I doubt this anyone will break this anytime soon if it means causing all pages using JQuery < 1.11 to break.

Comment: This warning also appears with jQuery 2.0.3 (most recent stable as of this comment), and the current milestone is set to 2.1, for the fix.

Comment: Does using jQuery 1.11 will fixe the issue?

Comment: Just to clarify... `jQuery` has *not* deprecated using `return false` in your click handlers? This is *Chrome* complaining about a snippet of code found inside the jQuery library?

Comment: Indeed. Chrome has deprecated `event.returnValue` which only existed for backwards compatibility with IE

Comment: I got the same error message by merely having `console.log(x)`, where x was mouseEvent (onclick). Chrome 33.0.1750.154. I'd consider it's a bug on Chrome's side by triggering the warning too loosely.

Comment: @F-3000 It is not a bug on Chrome's side. When you use jQuery, Chrome loads the jQuery library and parses it exactly like it would for a script you supplied. If you include jQuery, it will see that event.returnValue is used, and (correctly) throw the warning.

Comment: @kennycoc If jQuery actually had `event.returnValue`, then it indeed was jQuery's fault. But getting this warning with `console.log(mouseEvent)` definitely is a bug, as it very effectively disturbs debugging.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood what you were saying

Answer (score 23):

Just for other's reference, I just received this and found it was due to [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS).  It's for backwards compatibility:

```
if (!event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault = function() {
        event.returnValue = false; //ie
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error in a bare bones site with no angular being used or referenced - possibly indirectly referenced, but I doubt it.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: It's not an error, it's a warning. There's a big difference, especially in our context. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon If you include it at all, Chrome will parse it exactly the same as if it was a script you supplied, and (correctly) throw the warning.

Answer (score 20):

If you using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/):

The current version of Bootstrap (3.0.2) (with jQuery 1.10.2 & Chrome) seems to generate this warning as well.

(It does so on Twitter too, BTW.)

### Update

The current version of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) (3.1.0) no longer seems to generate this warning.

Answer (score 19):

That's your [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) problem, not your script. There is not much to worry about.

Answer (score 6):

This is a warning related to the fact that most JavaScript frameworks (jQuery, Angular, YUI, Bootstrap...) offer backward support for old-nasty-most-hated Internet Explorer starting from IE8 down to IE6 :/

One day that backward compatibility support will be dropped (for IE8/7/6 since [IE9 deals with it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), and you will no more see this warning (and other IEish bugs)..

It's a question of time (now [IE8 has 10% worldwide](http://theie8countdown.com/) share, once it reaches [1% it is DEAD](http://theie7countdown.com/)), meanwhile, just ignore the warning and stay zen :)

Comment: jQuery 2.x.x only supports IE9 and up. If you want IE8 support in jQuery you need to use version 1.x.x.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this warning on many websites. Also, I saw that [YUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library) 3 library also gives the same warning. It's a warning generated from the library (whether is it jQuery or YUI).

Answer (score 3):

I found that using the latest version will fix this problem:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js