# Links stopped working -- jquery issue?

Tags: jquery, python, html, css, django

I have links in a dropdown menu bar for navigation around my site.  Yesterday, they worked fine.  Today, they the menus no longer dropdown and the links that do display (in the headers) don't function like links (i.e. cursor doesn't change, they don't display the hover color change, etc.)  I even reverted to old commits to make sure I hadn't broken them, but they don't work at all, even for commits where I am 100% positive they used to.  When I do click on a 'link', I get the warning 'event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.' from a jQuery file.  I've tested on both Chrome and Firefox.  Normal links work fine, just not the ones in my navigation bar.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="/quiz/" >Quiz</a></li>
         <li><a href="/photos/">Photos</a></li>
         <li><a href="/story/" class="last">Our Story</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Edit:  That warning actually comes up whenever I click anywhere on the screen, not just on the links.

Edit:  http://jsfiddle.net/sLNHz/

Comment: You're preventing the default action somewhere in your javascript, only you know where ?

Comment: Hmm--not really sure how/where.  Any idea where I might look, or what to search for?

Comment: That's not about this warning, have a look at my recent question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/20045162/2795926. So it's just jquery's api warning, it shouldn't really affect your code now.

Comment: That's what I thought, but why would my links stop working all of a sudden?

Comment: Make sure there is nothing overlaying that menu! Do inspect element and check if any other `div` covers up your menu.

Comment: It's not, and honestly this was one of the first things on the site that I've coded, so it's worked for many commits.  I checked out an old version just to make sure--it used to work and now it doesn't, even on committed versions that were good.

Comment: I guess you'd better show us your jquery/javascript then.

Comment: I can/will, but even when I commented it all out so that only the menu headers showed (which are also links) they didn't work either.

Comment: The first thing you should do if you haven't already is to pull up the site in chrome right click then inspect element. then go to console and see what JavaScript errors may be getting thrown.

Comment: Yeah, nothing except that one (and some css warnings).  No errors, just warnings.

Comment: Maybe it's all about your stylesheet? You could probably disable your links with `pointer-events: none;`. Well, still I suppose you couldn't have overlooked that.

Comment: I don't understand how it's possible for an old commit that used to work now no longer does.

Comment: Change of jquery version?

Comment: I enabled `float:left`. It started working. In CSS for `#templatemo_menu ul`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fiddle, it's the `display: inline` on the `<ul>` element: That makes the whole thing collapsing to zero width and hence the links unclickable. The text is shown because of the default `overflow: visible`. So, it's a *CSS* issue, not a JS one.

Comment: Wow.  You are correct.  Do you have any idea why that used to work and now doesn't?  I can guarantee I haven't changed it--that line's been there a very long time.

Comment: When did you comment out the `float:left` on the `ul`? Floating changes the effective `display` (not the value set, but what the browser does with the element) to `block`. Basically, the issue arises, because someone changed from a float-based horizontal nav to a `display:inline`-based or vice versa and left half of the old statements in there. My suggestion: clear either the `inline` or the `float` declarations.