# Update textarea From User Input by jQuery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update a value in my php file and present it in a textarea using jquery and ajax. to make it short, I have:
1- A Form with User Input and Submit button and a Text area
2- A PHP file called data.php
3 -and the html file
Here is my codes

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<textarea name="wstxt" id="wstxt" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="button" name="txta-update" id="txta-update" value="Update Textarea"  />
</form>
```

PHP is as simple as:

```
<?php
$name = "Jordano";
echo $name;
```

and here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#txta-update').click(function() {

          $.ajax({ 
              type: "GET", 
              url: "data.php",//get response from this file
              success: function(response){ 

               $("textarea#wstxt").val(response);//send response to textarea
            }
        });
});
});
```

can you please tell me how I can send the input value to php and update the textarea from new value?
Thanks

**Update** 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send data like this

```
data:{name:$('input[name="name"]').val()}
```

you js file becomes

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "data.php", //get response from this file
     data:{name:$('input[name="name"]').val()},
     success: function (response) {

         $("textarea#wstxt").val(response); //send response to textarea
     }
 });
```

---

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txta-update').click(function () {
        var name_val = $('input[name="name"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data.php", //get response from this file
            data: {
                name: name_val
            },
            success: function (response) {

                $("textarea#wstxt").val(response); //send response to textarea
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

To get value in PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Tushar, thanks for your comment, well the first script didnt worked and I got this in teaxtarea when I used the second code: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: in the first method I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; " error on data:{name:$('input[type="name"]').val();},

Comment: @MonaCoder Use `data:{name:$('input[type="name"]').val()}` removed `;`  and read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045162/jquery-error-event-returnvalue-is-deprecated-please-use-the-standard-event-pre

Comment: Ok thanks  but it is returning bunch of tags insted of input! like : <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'> ....

Comment: Can you please take a look at update above? I just post the result image

Comment: @MonaCoder updated answer check update your php file.It's returning error.

Comment: Same! still same issue!

Comment: @MonaCoder do you have team viewer ?

Comment: Ok got it error is on $('input[type="name"]').val() should  be
$('input[name="name"]').val() thanks alot