# Why am I getting "event.returnValue is deprecated..." and how can I rectify it?

Tags: jquery, web, google-chrome-devtools, web-testing

In my web site, when I F12 from the browser, I see in the console (Chrome Dev Tools) the error/warning, "*event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.*"

Yet I search my project for "*event.returnValue*" and it turns up no instances of that string.

Assuming it is some Microsoft or jQuery-written code that is causing this, should I do something about it, and if so, what?

Comment: I get this as well, looks like it comes from JQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this ticket

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14320

This seems to be happening in the latest version of Chrome.  I guess you can not really do much about it but ignore it.

Comment: And this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045162/event-returnvalue-is-deprecated-please-use-the-standard-event-preventdefault/20995165#20995165